# path for chinese font with ConTeXt

Tags: fonts, context, cjk

I already use ConTeXt for maths and am fully satisfied, but now I need to write a document with text in chinese.

I've read the different PDFs (mchinese.pdf and Uptodate) available [here](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Chinese) and I visited various forums and tried the following 'hello world' script

```
\enableregime[utf]
\usemodule[chi-00]
\starttext
  你好！
\stoptext
```

I also tried [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41576/getting-started-with-chinese-in-context) one which sounds good for my use:

```
\setscript[hanzi]
\starttypescript [serif] [stfangsong]
      \definefontsynonym [Serif] [name:stfangsong][features=chinese]
\stoptypescript
\starttypescript [stfangsong]
      \definetypeface [stfangsong] [rm] [serif] [stfangsong] [default]
\stoptypescript
\setuppagenumber [numberconversion=cn]
\definestructureconversionset [chinese] [numbers] [cn]
\setupheads [sectionconversionset=chinese]
\define[2]\ChineseChapter
  {第#1章 #2}
\setuphead [chapter] [command=\ChineseChapter]
\setupbodyfont [stfangsong,12pt]
\mainlanguage[cn]
\setuppagenumbering[state=start]
\starttext
\startchapter[title={你好}]
你好！
\stopchapter
\completecontent[criterium=all]
\stoptext
```

But while compiling, well, both send me a blank pdf... I guess I have a problem with the fonts path.

Working on Ubuntu I have Adobe CNS1, Adobe GB1, ttf-wqyzenhei, various arphic and cwTex fonts installed, but I don't know how to call them properly. They are located in

```
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/ ( sometimes further in this dir for ex /usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/arphic/bkaiu)
```

Following http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Ubuntu, I tried typing

```
 export OSFONTDIR=~/.fonts:/usr/share/fonts:/usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/:/opt/libreoffice/basis3.3/share/fonts/
  mtxrun --script fonts --reload
  mtxrun --script fonts --list --all --pattern=*
  context --reload
```

as said in the page but despite no error, it doesn't change anything (is there a specific directory in which i should type this?)

I also read things about `.ttf`, `.pfb` (the format my fonts are installed in), and `.map`. I'm not sure if I even have `.map` file associated to my fonts and I did not understand how it works.

My last idea is that I don't use the proper name to call the fonts. For example, I'm not sure wheather 'stfangsong' is a name that calls a chinese font on my machine. I actually didn't find how ConTeXt understands font names in general.

Comment: There are three 'ConTeXt's---ConTeXt MkII based on XeTeX, ConTeXt MkIV based on LuaTeX and ConTeXt MkIII based on pdfTeX. Which one are you using?

Comment: With MkIV, you need to use TTF or OTF fonts

Comment: http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.context/20692/match=chinese