# Getting xeCJK package to work with MikTeX

Tags: xetex, cjk, xecjk

I am trying to write Chinese in LaTeX with MikTeX 2.9, and at the moment I am using fontspec, something like the below. However, I have heard good things about xeCJK, and I am considering switching to it instead (not least to improve the  looks of punctuation), however, I can't get it to work.

This is a document that works right  now

```
   \documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}

    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{SimSun}
    %\usepackage{xeCJK}

    \begin{document}
    %\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{SimSun}
    你好
    %\end{CJK}
    \end{document}
```

, however this document

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}

%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{SimSun}
\usepackage{xeCJK}

\begin{document}
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{SimSun}
你好
\end{CJK}
\end{document}
```

gives an `! Undefined control sequence <argument> \tipaencoding` error.

Can anyone help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{SimSun} \end{CJK} is CJK, which is not inherited by xeCJK(see bilingual [documentation](http://www.tex.ac.uk/CTAN/macros/xetex/latex/xecjk/xeCJK.pdf)). More better way to handle Chinese is using `ctex`

Try

```
% !TEX program = xelatex
% !Mode:: "TeX:UTF-8"
%Save as UTF-8, run xelatex.

\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setmainfont{Calibri}
\setCJKmainfont{宋体}

\begin{document}
Hello, 你好。

\end{document}
```

Comment: This returns the same error for me as the original code that was not working.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you should at first update `xunicode` package to avoid the error. I suggest you updating all packages if possible.

What's more, as Ma Ming pointed, you wrongly used `xeCJK` package. I have several answers on this topic. eg.
[How does one type Chinese in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17611/how-does-one-type-chinese-in-latex)