# Are there any good Chinese beamer templates available for Linux TeX Live users?

Tags: beamer, cjk

I have tested a few templates trying to write slides containing ***Chinese*** words with TeX Live (from Ubuntu 11.10 repositories). However, it always turned out that some macros were not found despite that the **`latex-cjk-all`** package has been installed. 
So I would like to know whether there are some nice templates for Linux users.

Comment: Related: [How does one type Chinese in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17611/how-does-one-type-chinese-in-latex)

Comment: Just use beamer with any CJK support above available on your system. Ubuntu has outdated texlive package, you'd better not use it.

Comment: @LeoLiu Could you make your comments here into an answer?

Comment: @JosephWright: Done.

Comment: @LeoLiu thanks so much for your answers below.

Comment: @HongxuChen: You may [accept the answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer) instead of say thanks in the comments, if the solution helps.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's nothing new in `beamer`.

### Recommended solution:

```
% Compile with XeLaTeX, with Chinese fonts installed with Windows as default.
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[noindent,UTF8]{ctexcap}
\renewcommand\CJKfamilydefault{\CJKsfdefault}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{中文}
在 beamer 中使用中文。
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

If you use latest version of `ctex` package in the SVN trunk, the solution can be also compile with pdfLaTeX. (In fact the solution can be compiled with `latex`/`pdflatex` if we don't change `\CJKfamilydefault`.)

For Linux users, one may have to specify the fonts explictly:

```
\usepackage[nofonts,noindent,UTF8]{ctexcap}
\renewcommand\CJKfamilydefault{\CJKsfdefault}
\setCJKsansfont{WenQuanYi Zen Hei}
```

### Solution using raw `xeCJK`

Everything is similar except that one must specify the Chinese fonts explictly.

```
% UTF-8 encoding, compile with XeLaTeX
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\renewcommand\CJKfamilydefault{\CJKsfdefault}
\setCJKsansfont{Microsoft YaHei}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{中文}
在 beamer 中使用中文在 beamer 中使用中文。
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The font `Microsoft YaHei` can be replaced with any font. For example Linux users may prefer

```
\renewcommand\CJKfamilydefault{\CJKsfdefault}
\setCJKsansfont{WenQuanYi Zen Hei}
```

or just

```
\setCJKmainfont{WenQuanYi Zen Hei}
```

---

Only XeLaTeX solutions are provided here. These solutions are more mature and easier to use than other solutions using `CJK` (for pdfLaTeX) or `luatex-ja` (for LuaLaTeX). Anyway you may refer other sources to use them.