# Problems with CJK in MiKTeX 2.9 on Windows 7

Tags: fonts, miktex, cjk

I have always had a problem with the proper configuration of the CJK package.
Here is a sample file that I would normally try to compile.

```
\documentclass[jcp,aip,preprint,superscriptaddress]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{CJK}

\begin{document}
\begin{CJK*}{GBK}{}

\title{Paper Title}

\author{L. Wang (ÍõÁ¢·É)}
\affiliation{School 1}

\author{Y. Zheng (Ö£Óê¾ü)}
\affiliation{School 2}

\begin{abstract}
This is the abstract.
\end{abstract}
\maketitle

\section{introduction}

Hello

\end{CJK*}
\end{document}
```

Here is the error I receive when I try to render the PDF.

```
Process started

Trying to make PK font gbk50 at 720 DPI...

Running miktex-makemf.exe...

miktex-makemf: The gbk source file could not be found. Running ttf2pk.exe...

miktex-makepk: PK font gbk50 could not be created. cjk_test2.dvi -> cjk_test2.pdf [1 ** WARNING ** Could not locate a virtual/physical font for TFM "gbk50". ** WARNING ** >> There are no valid font mapping entry for this font. ** WARNING ** >> Font file name "gbk50" was assumed but failed to locate that font. ** ERROR ** Cannot proceed without .vf or "physical" font for PDF output... Output file removed.

Process exited with error(s)
```

So I think I am missing a font. That is why MiKTeX is trying to create the fonts. I have tried to find a gbk50 font with no luck.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Why don't you use xeCJK and xetex instead? Are there any advantages of pdftex over xetex at all?

Answer (score 1):

This is simply because you wrongly use `CJK` package. If you have installed `cjk-fonts` package in MiKTeX, you can use:

```
\begin{CJK*}{GB}{gbsn}
```

instead of

```
\begin{CJK*}{GBK}{}
```

There are various methods to typeset Chinese in LaTeX, see [How does one type Chinese in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17611/how-does-one-type-chinese-in-latex)

Comment: This was the perfect solution.