# Use of Chinese numers similar to \Roman and \Arabic

Tags: xetex, numbering, cjk

When formatting sections, I see things like `\renewcommand \thesection{\Roman{section}}`.

I'm currently working on a set of Japanese History course notes, how would one go about defining a `\Chinese` command to use chinese/japanese numbering for my chapter headings?

Alternatively, if someone could point me to the place in the LaTeX codebase where I could find the particular definition that would work as well. I attempted to grep and find in my texlive installation but failed to find it.

Comment: Is this the kind of numerals that you mean? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_numerals

Comment: Yes those numerals, e.g., 一二三四五。。。

Comment: @EricR Can you provide [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) so that we know how you use which fonts?

Comment: Sorry @Qrrbrbirlbel, an MWE is a bit hard to extract at this point (working on a custom class), but I'm using fonts via 
`\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{DFKai-SB}`. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: @EricR The reason why I was asking for that information was to reassure that my answer (`zhnumber`) was working with your setup. I've never used Chinese or Japanese character and I could not validate the results I got (correct numbers?).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel, I've marked as correct since the documenation says that should work (my chinese is passable), however I'm getting the error for out of date `l3kernel l3packages`. I'm going to update to texlive2012 soon and I'll update this accordingly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is the [`zhnumber`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/zhnumber) package. The [documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/zhnumber) might tell you more than me …

### MWE <sub><sup>(by [Leo Liu](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17637/16595))</sup></sub>

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{SimSun}
\usepackage{zhnumber}
\renewcommand\thesection{\zhnum{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\zhnum{subsection}}
\begin{document}
\section{One}
\setcounter{section}{9}
\section{Ten}
\subsection{Ten.One}
\setcounter{section}{74}
\section{Seventy four}
\setcounter{section}{999}
\section{One thousand}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]