# Date and time macros in Chinese

Tags: counters, xecjk

Is there a way to get time and date stamps, or other standard counters, to appear in Chinese? I am using `xeCJK`.

Package `babel` (with `\selectlanguage{french}` etc. in context) makes it simple for the major European languages.

Comment: Can you explain, what you want to do and how the output should look like? A [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) would be helpful. Have you seen [Use of Chinese numers similar to \Roman and \Arabic](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/75589). `\zhdate{\year/\month/\day}` (or `\zhtoday`) produces “2013 年 2 月 1 日” with the `zhnumber` package.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: The various commands in the `zhnumber` package solve all of my problems — thank you! Why don't you submit this as the answer and I'll approve it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The package [`zhnumber`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/zhnumber) provides many macros to convert numbers, counters, dates and times into their Chinese representation.

Unfortunately, I can only understand the macro and option names in the [manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/zhnumber).

In [Use of Chinese numers similar to \Roman and \Arabic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/75589) you can find another example that uses LaTeX counters.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{SimSun}
\usepackage{zhnumber}
\begin{document}
Date: \zhtoday

Time: \zhcurrtime

\zhnumsetup{time=Chinese}
Date: \zhtoday

Time: \zhcurrtime

\zhnumsetup{time=Arabic}
1586/08/17: \zhdate{1586/08/17}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]