# fonts - horizontal chinese numerals

Tags: fonts

The page here

[Use of Chinese numers similar to \Roman and \Arabic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75589/use-of-chinese-numers-similar-to-roman-and-arabic)

shows how to produce Chinese numerals, but according to Howard Eves' history of math textbook, these numerals should be displayed vertically. How might that be achieved? I know a similar question was posed (and solved) about Maya numerals here:

[horizontal maya numerals (mathabx)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142257/horizontal-maya-numerals-mathabx)

How might the same effect be achieved in regards to Chinese numerals? For a visual example of what I mean, see an example from Eves' book: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0bpi.jpg

Comment: The `stackengine` package is adept at stacking things vertically, but your question does not indicate the context in which these vertically stacked numbers might be used, so it is hard to propose a particular solution.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes How would you like me to specify the context? The last link I provided that shows a page from Eves' text is the context I want the symbols to be displayed in (i.e., set in the middle of the page). The "context", if I am understanding you correctly, is the exact same as that of the Mayan numerals question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compiled with XeLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\setCJKmainfont{SimSun}
\usepackage{zhnumber}
\newcounter{Zhnum}
\def\ZH#1{\setcounter{Zhnum}{#1}{\normalsize\zhnum{Zhnum}}}
\def\nZH#1{{\scriptsize\bfseries#1} \ZH{#1}}
\begin{document}

\Longstack{
  1 \ZH{1}\\
  2 \ZH{2}\\
  3 \ZH{3}\\
  4 \ZH{4}\\
  5 \ZH{5}\\
  6 \ZH{6}\\
  7 \ZH{7}\\
  8 \ZH{8}\\
  9 \ZH{9}
} 
~~~or maybe this~~~
\Longstack{
  \nZH{1}\\
  \nZH{2}\\
  \nZH{3}\\
  \nZH{4}\\
  \nZH{5}\\
  \nZH{6}\\
  \nZH{7}\\
  \nZH{8}\\
  \nZH{9}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With XeLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{CJKnumb}
\setCJKmainfont{Apple LiSung} % or any other Chinese font 

\newcommand{\VZH}[2][c]{%
  \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}
  \ZHvertdigit#2\ZHvertdigit
  \end{tabular}%
}
\makeatletter
\def\ZHvertdigit#1#2\ZHvertdigit{%
  \CJKnumber{#1}%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi
  {\\\ZHvertdigit#2\ZHvertdigit}%
}

\begin{document}
\VZH{123} \VZH{5468} x \VZH[t]{987}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The optional argument to `\VZH` specifies the vertical alignment for the `tabular`.

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish the vertical alignment with pdfTeX?

Comment: @induktio How do you produce the Chinese digits, in the first place? Sorry, but I'm not going to do research about this.

Comment: I'm guessing that requires using XeLaTeX? All I know is I'm using pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX with MikTeX and I'm trying to do what I described above, but I clearly have no idea what I'm doing.

Comment: @induktio I'm quite sure there is a way to produce Chinese numerals with pdfLaTeX; I don't know how, but when the method is available, it should be easy to adapt the macro above. Maybe you can ask a precise question about the general problem of Chinese numerals with pdfLaTeX.