# fonts - Producing Chinese numerals with pdfLaTeX

Tags: fonts

As mentioned here:

[fonts - horizontal chinese numerals](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210685/fonts-horizontal-chinese-numerals/210704?noredirect=1#comment492868_210704)

I am trying to produce Chinese numerals in a vertical fashion, but I was wondering how you could do this with pdfLaTeX (both examples in the link above were done with XeLaTeX). My overall goal is to use pdfLaTeX to generate Chinese numerals in the following fashion:

[image]

Comment: Not a solution, but if it is just used once. Then you could just use xelatex to generate just this list. Then include it as a PDF.

Comment: @daleif If I were to use your approach, then how would I create a PDF that exclusively used what numerals I produced? That is, I don't want a full page PDF but just what I need to capture my numeral representation. I tried using tikz and tikzpicture but that did not really seem to work. Do you have a solution for that?

Comment: (1) in the doc you use to create e the image, make sure to remove the headers and footers, ie use the empty page style.  (2) create the PDF with xelatex. (3) you can crop the PDF from, say, A4 to a usable image use the pdfcrop command line tool to create a cropped image

Answer (score 3):

It's not impossible without using XeLaTeX, but it doesn't work very well. You can use the `CJKvert` package to combine horizontal and vertical text, but the kerning is terrible and characters often overlap (although `bkai` looks alright).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage[usebaselinestretch]{CJKvert}
\usepackage{setspace,rotating}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage[encoding=UTF8]{zhnumber}
\def\nZH#1{{\scriptsize\bfseries#1} \zhnumber{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{bkai}\CJKhorz
\begin{minipage}[t]{8em}
\centering
Example: 5625

\rotatebox{-90}{
\CJKvert\zhnumber{5625}
}
\end{minipage}
\qquad
\belowbaseline{\Longstack[r]{
  0 \zhnumber{0}\\
  1 \zhnumber{1}\\
  2 \zhnumber{2}\\
  3 \zhnumber{3}\\
  4 \zhnumber{4}\\
  5 \zhnumber{5}\\
  6 \zhnumber{6}\\
  7 \zhnumber{7}\\
  8 \zhnumber{8}\\
  9 \zhnumber{9}\\
  10 \zhnumber{10}\\
  100 \zhnumber{100}\\
  1000 \zhnumber{1000}\\
  10000 \zhnumber{10000}\\
}
\qquad
\Longstack[r]{
  \nZH{0}\\
  \nZH{1}\\
  \nZH{2}\\
  \nZH{3}\\
  \nZH{4}\\
  \nZH{5}\\
  \nZH{6}\\
  \nZH{7}\\
  \nZH{8}\\
  \nZH{9}\\
  \nZH{10}\\
  \nZH{100}\\
  \nZH{1000}\\
  \nZH{10000}\\
}
\qquad
\Longstack[r]{
  \zhdigits{0}\\
  \zhdigits{1}\\
  \zhdigits{2}\\
  \zhdigits{3}\\
  \zhdigits{4}\\
  \zhdigits{5}\\
  \zhdigits{6}\\
  \zhdigits{7}\\
  \zhdigits{8}\\
  \zhdigits{9}\\
  \zhdigits{10}\\
  \zhdigits{100}\\
  \zhdigits{1000}\\
  \zhdigits{10000}\\
}
}
\end{CJK*}

\end{document}
```