# Unicode characters in pdflatex output using hexcode without UTF-8 input

Tags: pdftex, unicode

I want to use Unicode characters (for Korean language, i.e. Hangul:
U+AC00 - U+D7A3; maybe also U+1100 - U+11FF) in the output of
latex(/pdflatex) while the LaTeX source file should be coded in
7 bit ASCII as before.

I would like to have something similar to `\ding{number}` for ZapfDingbats
for Unicode selected via its hexcode, something like:

```
\unicodechar{bc73}
```

to generate a character.
The output should be generated as before:

```
latex -> dvips -> ps2pdfwr
```

Until now I have only seen unicode examples using UTF-8 encoding
in source code - which is not an option for me - and typically
using xelatex (disrupting my book - having problems with the packages
I am using).
I use TeXLive 2012 (Debian) fully installed (incl. CJK package)
under Xubuntu 12.10, so in principle the fonts should be there.

I would really appreciate any answer or at least a hint to the
solution - or in worst case a reason why this may not be possible
at all.

NEWLY ADDED:
Please read the facts above.
No comment or answer is even near the question - look at unicode questions
here - this question is  totally different.
No German Umlaute or Eurosign - that's simple.
No entering of Unicode chars in the editor or elsewhere,
only visible in the output.
No XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

Just an example to print Hangul characters under conditions given above
or a reason why it won't work with latex/pdflatex - please.

Comment: Is the package conflicting with xetex `CJK`? Why not `xeCJK`?

Comment: Use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

Answer (score 8):

Well in theory you can type your whole text in ascii, you only need to know which octets (8-bit-packets) to use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

Euro (€): ^^e2^^82^^ac

ä: ^^c3^^a4

\end{document}
```

The main problem is to get the utf8-hex-notation (e282ac) from the unicode name (U+20AC). In theory it can be calculated (and inputenc is doing it when processing `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{20AC}{\texteuro}`) but I don't know a simple way to use the inputenc commands to get the values.

This input notation should work with the cjk-package (with utf8-option) too.

With the ucs-package (loaded when you use the option utf8x) you can use the command `\unichar`. But you should be aware that ucs can clash with some packages, e.g. it is mentioned in the biblatex list of incompatible packages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\unichar{"00E4}
\unichar{"20AC}
\end{document}
```

I have no idea if it would work together with cjk.

cjk offers also some text commands to enter symbols, e.g. `\Li4 \chun1`. but I don't know if this covers your symbols too.

Answer (score 4):

I think `enctex` will allow you to do this.

First, write the unicode string in a `\message{¾}` (for example). Then compile your file, and you will see a multi-byte string on the output — `^^c2^^be` in this example.

Now, in the top of your file (or, even better, in a format), type `\mubyte \someTeXCommand ^^c2^^be\endmubyte` and `\mubytein=1`.

Compile your file (or your format) with the `enc` option (it requires `ini` option too, and LaTeX may require the `etex` option on top), and all should be fine — hopefully!

I personally keep a list of such encodings in my format, for example to typeset mathematics in unicode or use special characters in text such as “…”

Answer (score 3):

I just had a problem with this, and answers by @UlrikeFischer and @RD6137 are essentially correct, but I'll post a writeup here; although I'm not sure about the Hangul characters per se, I'll be focusing on "Unicode characters" and "hexcode" part of the question; all of this was tested with `pdflatex`.

> No German Umlaute or Eurosign - that's simple.

Actually, not simple ([Command \texteuro unavailable in encoding T1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191813/command-texteuro-unavailable-in-encoding-t1)) - just the complexity was hidden by the `textcomp` package.

First, let's focus on input. If I do this in my terminal (`bash` shell on Linux):

```
$ echo -n € | hexdump -C
00000000  e2 82 ac                                          |...|
00000003
```

... I can see that what I entered as `€` in the shell, is actually a sequence of three bytes: 0xE2, 0x82, and 0xAC. Maybe it would be easier to also use my script [utfinfo.pl](http://sourceforge.net/p/sdaaubckp/code/HEAD/tree/single-scripts/utfinfo.pl):

```
$ echo -n € | perl utfinfo.pl 
Got 1 uchars
Char: '€' u: 8364 [0x20AC] b: 226,130,172 [0xE2,0x82,0xAC] n: EURO SIGN [Currency Symbols]
```

This tells us that the character/glyph for Euro sign `€` is filed as entry number 8364 (hex 0x20AC) in the Unicode table - and encoded (as per UTF-8, I guess) as the sequence of bytes 226,130,172 ( 0xE2,0x82,0xAC in hex ); exactly the same one which `hexdump` gave us earlier. Which brings us to this:

> No entering of Unicode chars in the editor or elsewhere,

If this was a reference to @RD6137's `\message{¾}`, I believe that was just a suggestion for one method on how to obtain the actual byte sequence for a Unicode character. When you have a code like U+20AC, that is just the Unicode name - think of it as the integer index of the entry in the Unicode table. But that is *not* the actual byte sequence in UTF-8.

And the only think you can enter directly in a Latex source file are raw UTF-8 bytes, by using the double caret `^^` escape sequence (I think the two characters following this are interpreted as hexadecimal); so having the U+20AC Unicode index/name won't help you much - you need the actual UTF-8 byte sequence 0xE2,0x82,0xAC. (As mentioned earlier, there seem to be no conventient/easy Latex macros that automatically map from Unicode index to a UTF-8 byte sequence).

So by entering `^^e2^^82^^ac` as ASCII text in the Latex source doc, Latex will parse this and interpret it as if you entered byte sequence 0xE2,0x82,0xAC - which would be the exact same result if you pasted the `€` character in a text editor, and saved the text file with UTF-8 encoding. However, if these three bytes are entered in a Latex doc, they will be interpreted as a single unicode character *only* if there is `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`! Otherwise, Latex will map them to individual glyphs to whatever is its current font setting.

Which brings us to another problem - font encoding. Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} % use font Latin Modern (lmodern / lmr)

\usepackage{fonttable}
\makeatletter
\def\myfontinfo{font: encoding \f@encoding, family: \f@family, series: \f@series, shape: \f@shape, size: \f@size, baselineskip: \f@baselineskip}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \typeout{\myfontinfo} % write to stdout
  \myfontinfo           % typeset in document
  , ^^e2^^82^^ac %
  \vspace*{-2em}
  \makeatletter
  %% \xfonttable{ encoding }{ family }{ series }{ shape }
  \xfonttable{\f@encoding}{\f@family}{\f@series}{\f@shape}
  \makeatother
\end{document}
```

If you compile this as-is, then Latex automatically assumes it's in OT1 encoding, which prints font table as on the image left (click for full size):

[image: /tmp/test-ot1.png]
[image: /tmp/test-t1.png]
[image: /tmp/test-ts1.png]

... and if you enable `[T1]{fontenc}` and recompile, Latex will use T1 encoding, generating a completely different font table - as on the middle image. You will note, since `[utf8]{inputenc}` is not specified, Latex interpreted `^^e2^^82^^ac` as individual characters `âĆň` in both cases, exactly as per the tables in each case (reading note for font table: left and top `'` are in octal; right and bottom `"` are in hex; so `%` which is 37 decimal, is `'04x`&`'5`=`'045` octal, and `"2x`&`'5`=`"25` hex; while `-` which is 45 decimal, is `'05x`&`'5`=`'055` octal, and `"2x`&`"D`=`"2D` hex).
However, you will also note that neither OT1 nor T1 contain the euro symbol - so where is it? It turns out, it is in another font encoding called `TS1`, and is on the rightmost image above (just use `[TS1]{fontenc}` in the MWE above), where it is glyph number 191 decimal (`'277` octal, `"BF"` hex).

So, if we just add `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` to the above example, it will now crash with:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:€ not set up for use with LaTeX.
See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                                  
l.15   , ^^e2^^82^^ac
                      %
?
```

We can superficially remedy that by using `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` - which now needs the Unicode index in hex, not the UTF-8 byte sequence. So, say you add `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{20AC}{TheEURO}` right after the `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`; you'll notice, now the sequence `^^e2^^82^^ac` results with just the word `TheEURO`! So, `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` can basically just call a macro for you when it encounters a binary/byte sequence that matches a Unicode character - but that is still in the same, current, font encoding (OT1 or T1 in the MWE above).

So what is needed in order to *typeset* a Euro sign - regardless if you enter it as `^^e2^^82^^ac` or as `€`, as now we discuss when `[utf8]{inputenc}` is enabled, - is that by `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` some macro is called, which will switch temporarily to TS1, and output glyph number 191 from there. That seems to be exactly what the `textcomp` package does (although I cannot figure out the numbering details):

```
$ grep euro `kpsewhich utf8enc.dfu`
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{20AC}{\texteuro}

$ grep euro `kpsewhich textcomp.sty`
    \space\space 4 = 5 + \string\texteuro\MessageBreak
\DeclareOption{euro}{\DeclareEncodingSubset{TS1}{?}{4}}
\def\tc@fake@euro#1{%
\DeclareTextCommandDefault{\texteuro}
   {\CheckEncodingSubset\UseTextSymbol{TS1}\tc@fake@euro5\texteuro}
```

So if instead of `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{20AC}{TheEURO}`, you add `\usepackage{textcomp}` after `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, you will see `^^e2^^82^^ac` in the Tex source typeset as `€` glyph in the pdf.

To come back to the Hangul characters: if I have the characters, I can find both their Unicode indexes, and UTF-8 byte sequences:

```
$ echo -n 각갓갥갷 | perl utfinfo.pl 
Got 4 uchars
Char: '각' u: 44033 [0xAC01] b: 234,176,129 [0xEA,0xB0,0x81] n: HANGUL SYLLABLE GAG [Hangul Syllables]
Char: '갓' u: 44051 [0xAC13] b: 234,176,147 [0xEA,0xB0,0x93] n: HANGUL SYLLABLE GAS [Hangul Syllables]
Char: '갥' u: 44069 [0xAC25] b: 234,176,165 [0xEA,0xB0,0xA5] n: HANGUL SYLLABLE GAELG [Hangul Syllables]
Char: '갷' u: 44087 [0xAC37] b: 234,176,183 [0xEA,0xB0,0xB7] n: HANGUL SYLLABLE GAEH [Hangul Syllables]
```

... and using `[utf8]{inputenc}`, we can easily enter, say, `^^ea^^b0^^81` (the UTF-8 byte sequence in hex) in the Latex document for the `'각' HANGUL SYLLABLE GAG`; and even define a handler for it, using `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{AC13}{\myHangulGAGhandler}` (using the Unicode index in hex) - the problem is, we'd need to know which font *and* in which font encoding has that glyph (and at what location), so that we could program `\myHangulGAGhandler` to select and typeset that glyph. And unfortunately, I know nothing of Hangul/Korean fonts (alghough, I have a `CJKutf8` example in [How does one type Chinese in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17611/how-does-one-type-chinese-in-latex/187158#187158), which might be useful as a starting point). In any case, using the above code to inspect font settings (also with a font table) in Latex documents, that you know are compiling well to Hangul/Korean, might be of help.

Otherwise, as far as using the Unicode index hex directly to output a character as in `\unicodechar{bc73}`, there seems to be no convenient macro for that; although as @UlrikeFischer noted, `\inputenc` already does that in the background - since it has to convert the `20AC` in  `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{20AC}...` to a byte sequence, to which it can react later. That is mighty complex, however; you can use something like this code:

```
...
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{trace}
\traceon
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{20AC}{TheEURO}
\traceoff
...
```

.. to get printouts like:

```
\UTFviii@tmp ->\UTFviii@three@octets €
{\expandafter}
{\expandafter}

\UTFviii@three@octets #1#2#3->\csname u8:#1\string #2\string #3\endcsname 
#1<-
#2<-�
#3<-�
{\expandafter}
....
```

... but in a shell, that looks all wrong; if the `.log` file is opened in `less` or a hex editor, you can see:

```
...
\UTFviii@three@octets #1#2#3->\csname u8:#1\string #2\string #3\endcsname 
#1<-<E2>
#2<-<82>
#3<-<AC>
{\expandafter}
{\csname}
...
```

... that `inputenc`, based on this `20AC` Unicode hex ID, creates a command which has the raw UTF byte sequence (0xE2,0x82,0xAC - or at least the first byte of it) in its name! (actually, I think `inputenc` somehow makes the byte 0xE2 an alias to the macro `\UTFviii@three@octets`, and in that way it "reacts" to extended UTF-8 characters). And understanding this requires knowledge not only of Latex internals, but also of actual UTF-8 encoding, which I think is partly the mechanism here - which I unfortunately don't have. Still, hope that this can be useful...

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227601/mapping-private-use-area-characters-in-pdflatex