# Unicode character ✔ (U+2714) not set up for use with LaTeX error while building with pdfTeX

Tags: pdftex, unicode, utf8

For the test case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifxetex}
\ifxetex
    \usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage{english}
    \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX}}
    \setmainfont[BoldFont=cmunbx.otf, ItalicFont=cmunti.otf, BoldItalicFont=cmunbi.otf]{cmunrm.otf}
    \setsansfont{CMU Sans Serif}
    \setmonofont{CMU Typewriter Text}
\else
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{textcomp}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\fi

\begin{document}
\section{Main}
Euro (€): ^^e2^^82^^ac\par
Heavy Check Mark (U+2714): ^^e2^^9c^^94\par
% ✔
\end{document}
```

got error:

```
Unicode character ✔ (U+2714) not set up for use with LaTeX. Heavy Check Mark (U+2714): ^^e2^^9c^^94
```

while building with **PDFLaTeX**.

There are lot of similar issues here, but even solution from the closest one ([Unicode characters in pdflatex output using hexcode without UTF-8 input](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89796/unicode-characters-in-pdflatex-output-using-hexcode-without-utf-8-input)) didn't work. How to fix it?

No such error while building with **XeLaTeX** (though it draws characters incorrectly, so suggestions how to fix it are also appreciated).

Comment: the `^^e2^^82^^ac` form will never work in xetex so you can remove the xetex testing in the preamble as that branch can not work. (or keep the xetex branch and delete these `^^` forms)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm still under impression of egreg's answer below, and among other things it make me doubt, whether need XeLaTeX at all. used PDFLaTeX for intermediate pdf builds and XeLaTeX for final. but it looks like recent LaTeX progress towards Unicode support and other things gradually erases the boundaries between them. is there any comparison available of PDFLaTeX Vs. XeLaTeX features, after LaTeX3 be released?

Comment: there will not be a latex3, and pdflatex will never have support for unicode _fonts_ pdflatex has some support for unicode input, mapping the utf-8 sequences to suitable tex macros but it is still fundamentally an 8 bit system.

Comment: under LaTeX3 I meant (latex-project.org/latex3), whatever it is. but thank you for clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hoping to have a file that compiles with both XeLaTeX and `pdflatex` is, I'm afraid, generally hopeless.

In any case, XeLaTeX doesn't accept input such as `^^e2^^82^^ac`; actually it does, but the result is not what you seem to expect.

You can set up replacements for missing symbols. I also redefine the Euro symbol for `pdflatex`, because the one you get with European Modern is “funny”.

```
\documentclass{article}

% general packages
\usepackage{iftex}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

% specific packages
\iftutex
  % XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX
  \usepackage{polyglossia}
\else
  % pdflatex
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage{pifont,eurosym}
\fi

% settings

\iftutex
  % XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX
  \setdefaultlanguage{english}
  %\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX}}
  \setmainfont{cmun}[
    Extension=.otf,
    UprightFont=*rm,
    BoldFont=*bx,
    ItalicFont=*ti,
    BoldItalicFont=*bi
  ]
  \setsansfont{CMU Sans Serif}
  \setmonofont{CMU Typewriter Text}
  \newfontface{\extrasymbols}{FreeSerif}[Extension=.otf]
  \newunicodechar{✔}{{\extrasymbols ✔}}
\else
    %\usepackage{textcomp}
    %\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \newunicodechar{✔}{\ding{52}}
    \newunicodechar{€}{\euro}
\fi

\begin{document}

Euro (U+20AC): €

Heavy Check Mark (U+2714): ✔

\end{document}
```

### Output with XeLaTeX

[image]

### Output with `pdflatex`

[image]

Comment: thank you for solution. additionally it revealed mess in the testcase, need to be fixed in the original file. was `inputenc` disabled because it has conflicts with `pifont` / other packages / settings, or just that it is unused in this particular case? the same question about `Ligatures={TeX}`.

Comment: @AlexShevchenko With an up-to-date LaTeX,  doing`\usepackage{textcomp}`, `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and setting `Ligatures=TeX` is no longer needed (albeit harmless).