# problem about typesetting Chinese characters in Latex

Tags: packages, languages, cjk

I found the post [How does one type Chinese in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17611/27987) about how to typeset Chinese in Latex. I just encountered the same problem, and my questions are:

1.To type Chinese or Japanese, I have to have some particular packages (such as CJK/XeCJK) installed, don't I?

2.I'm confused by the first solution in that post, it looks like this:

```
% UTF-8 encoding
% Compile with latex+dvipdfmx, pdflatex or xelatex
% XeLaTeX is recommanded
% Some Chinese fonts should be installed in your system (SimSun, SimHei, FangSong, KaiTi)
\documentclass[UTF8]{ctexart}
\begin{document}
文章内容。
\end{document}
```

The above solution just uses a class `ctexart` without any particular packages, and I tried to replace `ctexart` with `article`, it failed. So I wonder what is special about `ctexart` which can display Chinese without any add-on packages?

Comment: The `ctexart` document class itself loads `CJK` (if using pdflatex) or the `xeCJK` (if using xelatex) package, hence it works!

Comment: @LianTzeLim, so if I want to type CJK characters, I have to get those packages (CJK or XeCJK) ready anyway, right?

Comment: That's right. You can install these packages pretty easily via the package management tools that come with TeXlive or MikTeX.

Comment: @Mico, well, :-|

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. The following works pretty well in both LuaLaTeX and XeTeX without any special packages. `fontspec` (which I don't count among special packages) simply uses the SimSun font from Windows's font directory (as suggested in the code you're providing).

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{fontspec}
   \setmainfont{SimSun}
   \begin{document}
   文章内容。
   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]
2. `ctexart` simply loads the packages it needs, see LianTze Lim's comment.

Comment: Thanks, your `fontspec` solution works, but let me get it straight, why `fontspec` works? This package tell the tex engine how to handle the Chinese character?

Comment: [tag:fontspec] is a package that basically provides a connection between XeTeX or LuaTeX and the fonts installed on your system, particularly .otf and .ttf files. When using Xe or Lua, `fontspec` is almost a must-load, even for people typesetting texts in plain English. If I wanted to use Times New Roman, I'd simply use that same code I gave you, but say `\setmainfont{Times New Roman}` instead. Note that in traditional pdfTeX, `fontspec` is neither required, nor does it work, as fonts are handled differently there. [See](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/xetex/latex/fontspec/) also here.

Comment: So, I have to compile the .tex using `LuaTex` or `XeTex` if I use `fontspec`, right?

Comment: that is correct.

Comment: BTW, if I don't use `\setmainfont{SimSun}`, nothing shows in pdf, why? Without `setmainfont`, tex doesn't know how to do with the CJK characters? Furthermore, why use `\setCJKmainfont` when using package `CJK`? Can't I use `setmainfont`?

Comment: I can't say much about `CJK`-related issues. You might add that question to your original one. All I can say is: if you don't use `\setmainfont` at all, the »Latin Modern« fonts will be loaded, and these don't have CJK characters (as the name suggests).

Comment: This method doesn't work if I want the English text to be san serif font (\sffamily), any remedy?

Comment: can you specify »doesn't work«? Are you using `\setmainfont` and `\setsansfont` correctly?

Answer (score 1):

ctexart, ctexbook and ctexrep are the equivalent to "article", "book" and "report" of the standard classes. You should definitely use those if you have Chinese text.