# Type Chinese in TeX compiled with LaTeX

Tags: languages, cjk

I would like to type Chinese in TeX compiled with LaTeX. I have read the previous [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17611/how-does-one-type-chinese-in-latex). As I have to stick on `article` as `documentclass`, the following solution works for me so far:

```
% UTF-8 encoding
% bad-looking fonts (CJKfonts package)
% latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\begin{document}
\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}
文章内容。
\clearpage\end{CJK*}
\end{document}
```

It annoys me to have to enclose Chinese characters within an environment (`CJK*`). Isn't there a solution to type Chinese any time and any place we want, just as English characters?

**Edit 1:**

I tried the following code within `Emacs`, I use `C-c C-c` to launch `LaTeX` command within `Emacs`:

```
% Compile with xelatex
% UTF-8 encoding
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{SimSun}
\begin{document}
文章内容
\end{document}
```

It returns an error:

```
--- TeX said ---
 ********************************************
 * XeTeX is required to compile this document.
 * Sorry!
 ********************************************.
\RequireXeTeX ...********************************}
                                              \endgroup \fi 
l.25 \RequireXeTeX
```

But I have already done `sudo apt-get install texlive-xetex`, I have also installed `texlive-full`.

Comment: can you use `xelatex`?

Comment: It is confusing for me... should I install `xelatex` or `xetex`? I am under Ubuntu, and editing a tex under `Emacs`...

Comment: @SoftTimur a tex distribution will probably give you both if you ask for either.  you should be _using_ xelatex, though.

Comment: you actually want to launch `xelatex` command instead of `latex` (don't know how you do that on emacs, but on the command line is `xelatex mydoc`)

Comment: You should use `xelatex` rather than `latex`, or in `emacs`, if you are using `AucTeX`, you can achieve that by adding this code into you `.emacs` file: `(setq TeX-engine 'xetex)`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Using `CJK`

If you use `CJK` package, you can use `CJK` environment at the beginning and the end of the document only once. So you don't need to worry about where to put the `CJK` environment when you type the text. Say, you can (and you should) simply use

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\begin{document}
\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}

\chapter{某章}
内容……

\chapter{某章}
内容……

\clearpage\end{CJK*}
\end{document}
```

### Using `xeCJK`

As is said before, you should use `xelatex` command instead of `latex` command. And furthermore, you must specify a Chinese font installed in your Linux OS which can be listed via `fc-list` command.

It is typical that a default installation of Ubuntu does not have proper Chinese fonts installed. You can install WenQuanYi(文泉驿) and Arphic(文鼎) free fonts via `apt-get`, or you can manually install other commercial fonts.

Then use `fc-list` in a console window to get the font list in your OS. A typical list is like:

```
AR PL UMing TW:style=Light
AR PL UMing HK:style=Light
AR PL UMing CN:style=Light
AR PL UKai CN:style=Book
AR PL UKai HK:style=Book
AR PL UKai TW:style=Book
......
DejaVu Sans Mono:style=Bold
DejaVu Sans Mono:style=Book
DejaVu Sans:style=Bold
DejaVu Sans:style=Book
DejaVu Serif:style=Bold
DejaVu Serif:style=Book
......
WenQuanYi Zen Hei,文泉驛正黑,文泉驿正黑:style=Regular
WenQuanYi Zen Hei Mono,文泉驛等寬正黑,文泉驿等宽正黑:style=Regular
```

Some of these are Chinese fonts, some are not. You can choose a font name (before the `:`) to use, for example

```
% Compile with xelatex
% UTF-8 encoding
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{AR PL UMing CN} % may be changed
\begin{document}
文章内容
\end{document}
```

Note that the Chinese font names in different Linux distribution are quite different, e.g. you may get `AR PL SungtiL GB` for the same Arphic font. So don't just copy my code.

And you need to configure your Emacs to use `xelatex` instead of `latex` or `pdflatex`.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find a simple solution to your problem - just add two packages at the beginning of your document:

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}
```

This way your environment is set to English, but you can use Chinese at any time without setting CJK environment. You can list more languages from the babel package, just remember that the language you enter last is the one that will be the main one.