# How to add Chinese characters in header of thesis?

Tags: header-footer, chinese

I am writing a thesis and using **MasterDoctrolThesis.cls** format. This format shows the chapter name and heading of the current page in the header. I want to add Chinese specific character on each page of my thesis.
The code of **MasterDoctrolThesis.cls** for header is:

```
\RequirePackage[markcase=used]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\providepairofpagestyles{thesisSimple}{%
    \clearpairofpagestyles%
    \automark[chapter]{chapter}
    \ihead{\headmark}% Inner header
    \ohead[\pagemark]{\pagemark}% Outer header
}
\ifoot{}% Inner footer
\ofoot{}% Outer footer
\pagestyle{thesisSimple}
\providepairofpagestyles[thesisSimple]{thesis}{%
    \automark*[section]{}%
}
\providepairofpagestyles[thesisSimple]{review}{%
    \ofoot[\shorttitle/\authorname]{\shorttitle/\authorname}
    \ifoot[\today]{\today}
}
\pagestyle{thesis}
\ifbool{headsepline}{\KOMAoption{headsepline}{true}}{}
\PreventPackageFromLoading[\ClassError{\classname}{Package `fancyhdr' is
incompatible\MessageBreak with this class}{The pagesyles are defined 
    using package `scrlayer-scrpage', please consult the\MessageBreak 
KOMA-script documentation for details.}]{fancyhdr}


\newcommand{\blank@p@gestyle}{empty}
\newcommand{\chapter@p@gestyle}{plain}
\NewDocumentCommand{\blankpagestyle}{ m }{%
    \ClassWarning{\classname}{\string\blankpagestyle\space is
    obsolete,\MessageBreak use \string\setblankpagestyle \space  instead}\renewcommand{\blank@p@gestyle}{}{#1}
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\setblankpagestyle}{ m }{\renewcommand{\blank@p@gestyle}{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\setchapterpagestyle}{ m }{\renewcommand{\chapter@p@gestyle}{#1}}

\DeclareDocumentCommand\cleardoublepage{}{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
    \hbox{}
    \thispagestyle{\blank@p@gestyle}
    \newpage
    \if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi%
}
```

I need to add the follwing characters given in the picture in my **header**.
[image]

and need to put just red line in footer like:
[image]

For this the following code I have used, but it could not work:

```
\pagestyle{fancy} % all pages will follow same fancy header and footer style except title page
\fancyhf{} % Clear header and footer
\fancyhead[C]
{\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gkai}
        \fontsize{20}{20} \textbf{华\hspace{0.5cm}中\hspace{0.5cm}科\hspace{0.5cm}技\hspace{0.5cm}大\hspace{0.5cm}学\hspace{0.5cm}研\hspace{0.5cm}究\hspace{0.5cm}生\hspace{0.5cm}院} \end{CJK*}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.7pt} % Line at the header visible
```

How should I do this? Please help me out to this problem?

Comment: If you want to use the `CJK*` environment, it appears that you may want to add the command `\usepackage{CJKutf8}`. Another option is XeCJK.

Comment: See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107898/type-chinese-in-tex-compiled-with-latex

Comment: Do not change the class file.

Comment: `\clearpairofpagestyles\cfoot*{\pagemark}\chead{\textbf{华\hspace{0.5cm}中\hspace{0.5cm}科\hspace{0.5cm}技\hspace{0.5cm}大\hspace{0.5cm}学\hspace{0.5cm}研\hspace{0.5cm}究\hspace{0.5cm}生\hspace{0.5cm}院}` (And the stuff to get the chinese working)

Comment: @Johannes_B This code is showing error: ` ! Paragraph ended before \@@chead was complete.<to be read again>\par  `

Comment: Is there any way to change some code in **MasterDoctoralThesis.cls** header code mentioned in the question?

Comment: @Johannes_B I am looking forward to you? please give me a response?

Comment: I haven't been on my desk for over twelve hours and i won't br at it for maybe a day.  You have to be patient.

Comment: @Johannes_B okay, please. I am waiting

Comment: So the error you have been reporting for the code snippet i gave you earlier is due to one missing brace that closes the `chead` command. I didn't test the snippet (obviously), but the error message and an editor with code highlighting and brace matching should have made it obvious.

Comment: Is there any news here?

Answer (score 1):

Add `footsepline` to the global options.

```latex
headsepline, % Uncomment to get a line under the header
footsepline,% <-------
%chapterinoneline, % Uncomment to place the chapter title next to the number on one line
%consistentlayout, % Uncomment to change the layout of the declaration, abstract and acknowledgements pages to match the default layout
]{MastersDoctoralThesis} % The class file specifying the document structure

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters

%\usepackage{mathpazo} % Use the Palatino font by default
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif CJK}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\cfoot*{\pagemark}
\chead{华\hspace{0.5cm}中\hspace{0.5cm}科\hspace{0.5cm}技\hspace{0.5cm}大\hspace{0.5cm}学\hspace{0.5cm}研\hspace{0.5cm}究\hspace{0.5cm}生\hspace{0.5cm}院}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\color{red!80!black}}
```

On my very old installation, LuaTeX refuses to find the bold font weights. I won't did deeper into this, as the issue is most likely gone with a fresh installation of TeX Live, or the solution for TL17 would be obsolete.