# error on generating pdf by Latex with CJK support

Tags: unicode, cjk, sphinx

After adding unicode characters to `\title{}` micro:

```
\title{标题}
```

the following error occurs when running `make all-pdf` with a `.tex` file:

```
Writing index file mybook.idx
No file mybook.aux.
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/t1ptm.fd)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cjk/texinput/UTF8/UTF8.bdg)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cjk/texinput/UTF8/UTF8.enc)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cjk/texinput/UTF8/UTF8.chr)
! Extra \else.
\CJK@XXX ...\number `#1\endcsname {`#2}{`#3}\else
                                                  \csname u8:\string #1\stri...
l.124 \tableofcontents

?
```

I have added the follow setting to the `.tex` file:

```
\hypersetup{unicode=true}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\AtBeginDocument{\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}}
\AtEndDocument{\end{CJK}}
```

If I remove the unicode characters, and replace them with acsii characters, it works well. If anything I forgot to add to the `.tex` to achieve this?

---

the minimal `.tex` file to reproduce the error:

```
% Generated by Sphinx.
\def\sphinxdocclass{report}
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt,english]{sphinxmanual}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00A0}{\nobreakspace}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[Bjarne]{fncychap}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{sphinx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\AtBeginDocument{\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}}
\AtEndDocument{\end{CJK}}

\title{title 中文}
\date{June 21, 2013}
\release{1.0.0}
\author{author}
\newcommand{\sphinxlogo}{}
\renewcommand{\releasename}{Release}
\makeindex

\makeatletter


\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\printindex
\end{document}
```

the specific error message:

```
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))
(./mybook.out) (./mybook.out)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cjk/texinput/UTF8/UTF8.bdg)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cjk/texinput/UTF8/UTF8.enc)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cjk/texinput/UTF8/UTF8.chr)
! Extra \else.
\CJK@XXX ...\number `#1\endcsname {`#2}{`#3}\else
                                                  \csname u8:\string #1\stri...
l.32 \tableofcontents

?
```

if I remove the unicode characters from `\title{title 中文}` into `\title{title}`, it works well.

Comment: Please add a _full_ [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Make sure to _only_ include the code that is necessary to reproduce the problem and nothing else.

Comment: Alternatively, you may just add something like "\usepackage[slantfont,boldfont]{xeCJK}
\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
%\setCJKmainfont{Adobe Fangsong Std}
", and try to use xelatex to compile the tex file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick fix:

```
\title{title \unexpanded{中文}}
```

Your problem is caused by an unusual definition of `\maketitle` in `sphinxmanual` class.

In the definition of `\maketitle` of `sphinxmanual.cls`, there is

```
\pdfinfo{
  /Author (\@author)
  /Title (\@title)
}
```

It's very dangerous since CJK chracters are actually macros and should not be put into pdf streams directly. So we can use eTeX's primitive `\unexpanded` to prevent the problem.

For more about Chinese typesetting, see [How does one type Chinese in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17611/how-does-one-type-chinese-in-latex) XeLaTeX can also solve the problem.

Comment: I use python-sphinx to generate the `.tex` file. Is there any fix for sphinx's conf.py to achieve this? I'd like to finish pdf generation in one step without generating `.tex` file firstly, then fixing it manually, finally generating `.pdf`.

Comment: @geeker: Modify `sphinxmanual.cls` to add `\unexpanded`.