# How to type Chinese characters in ShareLaTeX?

Tags: cjk, sharelatex

I'm going to type a few of Chinese characters among a bunch of English sentences, 
for example:

> Note: the first ":" introduces an extensive description of the sememe "tool|用具", describing what kind of tool it is; the second ":" introduces a lower-level extensive description of the sememe "wash|洗涤", indication what is washed and what is its relation with the tool, agent, method, time or instrument.

What should I do?

Comment: There is a "Support & Feedback" link on the [ShareLaTeX](http://www.sharelatex.com) website; ask the support team if ShareLaTeX supports Chinese :) If not, [install TeX Live](http://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html)!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 7):

(Founder of ShareLaTeX here). We've followed this up through our help desk, but just for reference the following minimal example will compile in ShareLaTeX (taken from [How does one type Chinese in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17611/how-does-one-type-chinese-in-latex)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\begin{document}
\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}
文章内容。
\clearpage\end{CJK*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to mention the Disclosure: (Founder of ShareLaTeX here) at your profile page _also_ to benefit users outside of this post and thereby eliminate repetition.