# How can I show Unicode words in pdf

Tags: unicode, cjk

```
%% AMS-LaTeX Created by Wolfram Mathematica 9.0 : www.wolfram.com

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, graphics, setspace}

\newcommand{\mathsym}[1]{{}}
\newcommand{\unicode}[1]{{}}

\newcounter{mathematicapage}
\begin{document}

$\unicode{8bbe}\unicode{6709}\unicode{4e8c}\unicode{6b21}\unicode{591a}\unicode{9879}\unicode{5f0f}$

\begin{equation}
f(x,y)=x^2+x y+y^2
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I cannot see the Unicode words/Chinese words.

I use WinEdt/CTex

Comment: To type Chinese, you should read this post:
[How does one type Chinese in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17611/how-does-one-type-chinese-in-latex)

Comment: @LeoLiu Hi, [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33577/how-can-i-export-chinese-in-tex-file) my second example show typed Chinese works well, but how to show `unicode{...}`

Answer (score 4):

If you use a proper font with a modern TeX engine (XeTeX or LuaTeX), it is not difficult to typeset any Unicode glyph.

XeLaTeX is preferred for Chinese. To type Chinese, you should read this post:
[How does one type Chinese in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17611/how-does-one-type-chinese-in-latex)

Mathematica's output is not very well. It is better to fix the problem in some Mathematica way, if possible. Anyway, this is a patch for your code:

```
% UTF-8 encoding!
% Compile with XeLaTeX!
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, graphics, setspace}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{SimSun}

\newcommand{\unicode}[1]{\uppercase{\text{\symbol{"#1}}}}

\newcounter{mathematicapage}
\begin{document}

$\unicode{8bbe}\unicode{6709}\unicode{4e8c}\unicode{6b21}\unicode{591a}\unicode{9879}\unicode{5f0f}$

\begin{equation}
f(x,y)=x^2+x y+y^2
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works, thanks, do you happen use mathematica? one workaround is to change `unicode{8bbe}` into chinese by StringReplace. I've updated in Mathematica.SE

Comment: In my...Text Cell would still have inline dollar demileters `$sdfs$` by default.

Comment: @HyperGroups: Well, that's my fault.

Comment: `\uppercase{\text{\symbol{"#1}}}` is simpler

Comment: @egreg: You're right.