# Why can't I use Chinese in MiKTeX

Tags: miktex, cjk

This is my source code of a LaTeX file, I use the package `CJK` in the editor WinEdt, and MiKTeX, but the display result is bad, it cannot display Chinese characters.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{CJK}
\title{Test}
\author{zhulongsheng(11291065@bjtu.edu.cn)}
\date{2014/01/28}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{CJK*}{GBK}{song}
\today
\section{第一}
这是第一段
\CJKfamily{hei}
\section{第二}
这是第二段
\subsection{Goal}
这是
\LaTeX
\end{CJK*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: This might well be a problem of file encoding. Why aren't you using UTF-8?

Comment: @egreg Since `cp936`, very similar to `GBK`, is being used for Windows OS (Chinese Simp.), many old books and articles that are available on the Internet introduced the `CJK` package with `GBK` as the default solution. Consequently, it's very common that a beginner of LaTeX from China takes `CJK` with `GBK` as his/her solution.

Comment: @egreg: No, it isn't an encoding problem. It is a font problem.  CJK fonts for LaTeX `CJK` package need some extra configurations. These configurations are done by some local TeX distributions. For MiKTeX and TeX Live, we can use some more modern solutions (e.g. `zhmetrics`'s dynamic font mapping for pdfTeX/dvipdfmx; `xeCJK` for XeTeX).

Comment: A link in Chinese for simple Chinese typesetting: [如何在 LaTeX 中处理中文？请举一个例子。](http://bbs.ctex.org/forum.php?mod=redirect&goto=findpost&ptid=48244&pid=337082&fromuid=102734)

Answer (score 4):

The `CJK` package is old and not recommended. Here is a Unicode solution, using the `xeCJK` package and the `XeTeX` engine.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
% I supposed that you do have these fonts mentioned below.
\setCJKmainfont[BoldFont={SimHei},ItalicFont={[SIMKAI.TTF]}]
  {SimSun}
\setCJKsansfont{SimHei}
\setCJKmonofont{[SIMFANG.TTF]}
\setCJKfamilyfont{zhsong}{SimSun}
\setCJKfamilyfont{zhhei}{SimHei}
\setCJKfamilyfont{zhkai}{[SIMKAI.TTF]}
\setCJKfamilyfont{zhfs}{[SIMFANG.TTF]}
\newcommand*{\songti}{\CJKfamily{zhsong}} % 宋体
\newcommand*{\heiti}{\CJKfamily{zhhei}}   % 黑体
\newcommand*{\kaishu}{\CJKfamily{zhkai}}  % 楷书
\newcommand*{\fangsong}{\CJKfamily{zhfs}} % 仿宋
\title{Test}
\author{zhulongsheng(11291065@bjtu.edu.cn)}
\date{2014/01/28}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\today
\section{第一}
这是第一段
\heiti
\section{第二}
这是第二段
\subsection{Goal}
这是
\LaTeX
\end{document}
```

Save it as encoding `UTF8` and compile it with `XeLaTeX`.

Furthermore, if your operating system is Windows (Chinese Simp.), you would be glad to know the `ctexart` class, since it provides you an easy way to produce LaTeX document that contains Chinese chars.

A simple example (`UTF8` and `XeLaTeX`, also):

```
\documentclass[UTF8, cs4size]{ctexart}
\title{Test}
\author{zhulongsheng(11291065@bjtu.edu.cn)}
\date{2014/01/28}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\today
\section{第一}
这是第一段
\heiti
\section{第二}
这是第二段
\subsection{Goal}
这是
\LaTeX
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unicode `fontspec` solution without package `CJK`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{STFangsong} % Mac OS X system font
\setsansfont{STHeiti}    % Mac OS X system font
\newfontfamily\song{STFangsong}
\newfontfamily\hei{STHeiti}

\title{Test}
\author{zhulongsheng(11291065@bjtu.edu.cn)}
\date{2014/01/28}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\today

\song

\section{第一}
这是第一段

\hei%\sffamily%\CJKfamily{hei}

\section{第二}
这是第二段
\subsection{Goal}
这是
\LaTeX
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Why fails?

MiKTeX (and TeX Live) does not set proper font mapping for those fonts for `CJK` package. It is unportable and difficult to maintain such font mapping for so different platforms.

In some local TeX distributions (e.g. [CTeX套装](http://www.ctex.org/CTeXDownload)), extra font mapping is set up for Chinese version of Windows platform. Your code will work fine if you install these TeX distributions.

### Quick (and dirty) fix

```
% Put it in the preamble
\AtBeginDvi{\input{zhwinfonts}}
```

### Better solution

- XeLaTeX is preferred. pdfLaTeX or dvipdfmx is also fine. (LuaLaTeX is not yet fully supported.)
- UTF-8 encoding is prefered (especially for XeLaTeX).
- `ctex` package (`ctexart`, `ctexrep`, `ctexbook` classes) is prefered.

See [How does one type Chinese in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17611/how-does-one-type-chinese-in-latex) for my suggestion.