# Russian and Chinese in the same document

Tags: babel, cjk

I'm writing a document that is going to required having Russian, Chinese characters, and English.  I'm using CJK and babel and example code is below:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian, english]{babel}
\usepackage{CJK}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
слово
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}
你好
\end{CJK}

слово

\end{document}
```

The Russian that becomes before the CJK environment shows up fine, but anything afterwards doesn't display properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `CJKutf8` package instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian, english]{babel}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}

\begin{document}
слово
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}
你好
\end{CJK}

слово

\end{document}
```

Or, a XeTeX solution using `xeCJK` pacakge is also acceptable. See also [How does one type Chinese in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17611/how-does-one-type-chinese-in-latex/17637#17637)

Answer (score 3):

[image: Multilingual typesetting]

## Code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian, english]{babel}% note - it is recommended to specify the variant of English required to avoid unexpected divergence depending on the version of babel e.g. american or british
\usepackage[encapsulated]{CJK}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{russian}
слово

\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}
你好
\end{CJK}

\selectlanguage{english}
Here is some text in English.

\selectlanguage{russian}
слово

\end{document}
```

## Explanation

The `encapsulated` option is required because you are using specialised encodings outside of the `CJK` environments. For details run

```
texdoc cjk
```

## Notes

- You should *switch* languages using either `\selectlanguage{<language>}` (for a general switch until further notice) or `\foreignlanguage{<language>}{<some text>}` (if you just want to typeset a small amount of text in another language).
- You have defined `english` as the main language. So you need to switch to Russian even if it is the first language used in the document. Passing `english` is not a great idea because it is ambiguous and has different effects with different versions of `babel`. Better to specify the variant required such as `british` or `american`.
- If Russian should be the main language, you should use something like:

  `\usepackage[british,russian]{babel}`

  The *last* language passed to `babel` is assumed to be the first language used and the main language for the document.

Answer (score 3):

A simple way to display Chinese characters is to use the kotex package.

```
\usepackage{kotex}
```

The good thing about this package is that you don't need to encapsulate your Chinese characters. You can just write things like

```
你好
```

and they will display correctly in the PDF.

Comment: kotex is a package for Korean support, not Chinese.