# Change language to chinese (XeLaTeX, memoir, polyglossia)

Tags: xetex, memoir, cjk

I am writing a document, which is to be available in english, danish, german and chinese (so far). Changing between the first three languages is easily achieved; by substituting the desired language in the following two commands

```
\documentclass[english]{memoir}
```

and

```
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
```

references (tables, figures, ...), captions and headings (table of contents, bibliography, ...) are displayed in the correct language (I am using `cleveref` for references if that matters). Now the question is what to do to achieve the same result with chinese?

Note, this question is **not** about [how to type chinese in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17611/how-does-one-type-chinese-in-latex), but about how to get the auto generated "text bits" translated into chinese. In addition, since I am using a great deal of the memoir functionality, changing the document class to [ctexart](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/language/chinese/ctex) is not an option.

Is there any pretty solution available - or do a have to redefine the macros myself?

Comment: You should look into `xeCJK`; requires knowledge of Chinese, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it is not a Chinese document, I think `xeCJK` should be your first choice to support typesetting Chinese characters. Say,

```
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{some Chinese font you use}
% ...
```

However, there is no `babel`/`polyglossia` equivalent for Chinese. Roughly speaking, I think it is better to define a set of macros yourself.

It won't be difficult for most cases. A simple definition could be, for example:

```
\newcommand\chineselanguage{%
  \renewcommand\contentsname{目录}%
  \renewcommand\listfigurename{插图}%
  \renewcommand\listtablename{表格}%
  \renewcommand\indexname{索引}%
  \renewcommand\bibname{参考文献}%
  \renewcommand\figurename{图}%
  \renewcommand\tablename{表}%
}
```

For numders and date, `zhnumber` package provides some macros to get Chinese numbers, digits and date.