# why my chinese characters don't wrap?

Tags: miktex

```
\documentclass[18pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}%setmainfont的依赖
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\everymath{\displaystyle}%全局定义所有的inline元素按display元素展示
\setlength{\lineskiplimit}{10bp}%行间距界限
\setlength{\lineskip}{10bp}%触到界限重新设定行距
\geometry{a4paper,left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=2cm}
\color[rgb]{0.45,0.45,0.35}
\setmainfont{DENG.ttf}
\title{数列极限提纲}
\author{十五}
\begin{document}
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{4}%设置目录深度
\maketitle %显示标题
\large  
\boldmath
\tableofcontents%自动生成目录,根据section,subsection,subsubsection生成
\newpage
\section{前言}
在本节,我会介绍数列和其极限的基本概念,基本性质,出题模式,以及常规的计算思路.
在基本概念中,我会仔细解释数列极限和函数极限的异同,在基本性质中,在介绍与函数极限相同性质的基础上再新增一些数列极限应用更多的性质.
\section{数列极限基本概念}
\subsection{定义}
\subsubsection{数列的定义}

\subsubsection{数列极限的定义}
\subsection{性质}
\subsubsection{极限基本性质}
\subsubsection{无穷变量性质}
\subsubsection{运算法则}
\subsubsection{子列与总列}
\subsubsection{数列函数的极限}
%每一道题用尽可能的多种方法去做
\subsection{出题的区别}


\section{数列极限计算思路}
\subsection{归结原则}
\subsubsection{内容}
\subsubsection{例题}
\subsection{夹逼准则}
%泰勒非常好用,函数极限通常用不到夹逼准则
\subsubsection{内容}
\paragraph{命题}
\paragraph{适用题型}
\paragraph{额外的用法}
\subsubsection{例题}
\subsection{单调有界}
\subsubsection{内容}
\subsection{柯西收敛与压缩映射}
\subsubsection{内容}
\subsection{积分定义}
\subsubsection{内容}
\subsection{stolz定理}
\subsubsection{内容}
\subsection{杂例}
\subsubsection{拉中定理}
\subsubsection{级数性质}
\subsubsection{函数极值}%题目通常第一问让你求极值引导你思考.
\section{数列极限综合例题}

\end{document}
```

win10,
MikTex,
TeXstudio

the DENG.ttf is a chinese character ttf file.

I don't know how to solve the problem.

When I edit with English characters, it will auto wrap when the line is full of characters.

Comment: Related? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/193337/120578

Comment: Chinese input does not ordinarily have spaces between characters/words, while Western languages do, and it's the spaces that are the principal points where breaks are applied.  That's why a Chinese-centric package is required to enable line breaking.

Answer (score 1):

Please always use package `ctex` when you are typesetting Chinese

```latex
\documentclass[18pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{ctex}
\usepackage{fontspec} % setmainfont 的依赖
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\everymath{\displaystyle} % 全局定义所有的 inline 元素按 display 元素展示
\setlength{\lineskiplimit}{10bp} % 行间距界限
\setlength{\lineskip}{10bp} % 触到界限重新设定行距
\geometry{a4paper, left=1cm, right=1cm, top=1cm, bottom=2cm}
\color[rgb]{0.45,0.45,0.35}
% \setmainfont{DENG.ttf}
\title{数列极限提纲}
\author{十五}
\begin{document}
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{4} % 设置目录深度
\maketitle % 显示标题
\large  
\boldmath
\tableofcontents % 自动生成目录,根据 section, subsection, subsubsection 生成
\newpage
\section{前言}
在本节,我会介绍数列和其极限的基本概念,基本性质,出题模式,以及常规的计算思路.
在基本概念中,我会仔细解释数列极限和函数极限的异同,在基本性质中,在介绍与函数极限相同性质的基础上再新增一些数列极限应用更多的性质.
\section{数列极限基本概念}
\subsection{定义}
\subsubsection{数列的定义}

\subsubsection{数列极限的定义}
\subsection{性质}
\subsubsection{极限基本性质}
\subsubsection{无穷变量性质}
\subsubsection{运算法则}
\subsubsection{子列与总列}
\subsubsection{数列函数的极限}
% 每一道题用尽可能的多种方法去做
\subsection{出题的区别}


\section{数列极限计算思路}
\subsection{归结原则}
\subsubsection{内容}
\subsubsection{例题}
\subsection{夹逼准则}
% 泰勒非常好用，函数极限通常用不到夹逼准则
\subsubsection{内容}
\paragraph{命题}
\paragraph{适用题型}
\paragraph{额外的用法}
\subsubsection{例题}
\subsection{单调有界}
\subsubsection{内容}
\subsection{柯西收敛与压缩映射}
\subsubsection{内容}
\subsection{积分定义}
\subsubsection{内容}
\subsection{stolz定理}
\subsubsection{内容}
\subsection{杂例}
\subsubsection{拉中定理}
\subsubsection{级数性质}
\subsubsection{函数极值} % 题目通常第一问让你求极值引导你思考.
\section{数列极限综合例题}

\end{document}
```

I also commented `\setmainfont{DENG.ttf}`, which I do not have in my laptop, here is how it looks like

[image: wrap]