# LaTeX traditional Chinese doesn't support for some letter like ‘爲’

Tags: fonts, pdftex, cjk, chinese

I want to print out some traditional Chinese phrase “因爲所以”, but the letter “爲” is missing, what can I do? Linux with pdflatex.

```
%!TeX program = pdfLaTeX
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\begin{document}

\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{bsmi}
因爲所以，我愛中華
\end{CJK*}

\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{bkai}
因爲所以，我愛中華
\end{CJK*}

\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}
因爲所以，我愛中華
\end{CJK*}

\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gkai}
因爲所以，我愛中華
\end{CJK*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Compiling result with missing letter]

Comment: The `gbsn` and `gkai` fonts don't support those characters. Perhaps `g` means “simplified Chinese”?

Comment: do you have to use pdflatex? If you use xelatex or lualatex you would have a much wider choice of fonts available, and can choose any font available on your system that has those characters

Comment: @egreg You are right, `gbsn` and `gkai` are for simplified Chinese. but `g` stands for another meaning, I think it's `guobiao` 國標, means 'national standard of (China)'. My complaint here is that `bsmi` should principally support well the traditional letter like ’爲‘

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you, it seems I'd better to move to  `xelatex` and use `xeCJK` instead. However if my problem can be solved within `pdflatex` and `CJK`, I'd be happy.

Comment: pdflatex can only have 256 characters in a font so arranging a collection of fonts to cover Chinese is a lot of work and the internal mappings required to map an input character to some specific font that covers that 256 character subset are very complicated. It is of course possible in theory to set up a new font but given that any system opentype font "just works" with xetex or luatex, the incentive to set up new pdftex fonts is not great.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to input Traditional Chinese in pdfLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200449/how-to-input-traditional-chinese-in-pdflatex)

Comment: @erik thank you for the comment, I'm familiar with that answer. My question is different. You can notice that I use the same packages, but certain words are not properly complied, like '爲'.

Comment: Sorry, my misunderstanding. It looks like this is simply a font issue as noted by Mico's answer. The Chinese fonts `bmsi` and `bkai` seem to have 為 or 为, whereas the 爲 variant shows up in the Korean and Japanese fonts `min` and `mj`.

Comment: You might want to use `為` instead of `爲` with bsmi or bkai.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you free to switch to XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX? If so, there are any number of system fonts out there that can handle the glyph `爲`. For instance, Noto Serif CJK TC and Noto Sans CJK TC.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%% fontspec package requires either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif CJK TC}
\setsansfont{Noto Sans CJK TC}
\begin{document}
因爲所以，我愛中華 \qquad \sffamily 因爲所以，我愛中華
\end{document}
```

Comment: why the numbers in the text are not copyable in this font? e.g. any numbers like 2021

Comment: @user13720066 - I'm very sorry, but I don't understand your question. Please elaborate what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I mean, if your texts contains numbers like 'year 2021 is good', in the layout you couldn't search or copy this number, your copy only 'year is good', why?

Comment: I'm truly sorry, but I'm not the designer of this font, and I have no knowledge of any design decisions or choices thare were made when the font was created. Hence, I'm not in a position to answer questions related to *why* some features may or may not work.