# Vim + latex-suite + xelatex ，can not compile Simplified Chinese

Tags: xetex, vim, vim-latex

According to the instructions on this site: http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/index.php?subject=download .I have installed gvim80, vim-latex-1.9.0 on Windows10.The vim+latex-suite can compile pure English article.

I search arourd the Internet a lot time to configure Vim+latex-suite in order to use Xelatex to typesetting Chinses.I have change the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vimfiles\ftplugin\latex-suite\texrc` file. Here I list the changed settings:

The 1st change:

```
if has('macunix')

 TexLet g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat = 'dvi'

else

 TexLet g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat = 'pdf'
```

The 2nd change:

```
 " ways to generate pdf files. there are soo many...

 " NOTE: pdflatex generates the same output as latex. therefore quickfix is
 "       possible.

TexLet g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf = 'xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error-style $*'
```

The 3rd change:

```
if has('win32')
    TexLet g:Tex_ViewRule_ps = 'gsview32'
    TexLet g:Tex_ViewRule_pdf = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32'
    TexLet g:Tex_ViewRule_dvi = 'yap -1'.
```

after finish the configuration .I write a tex file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ctex}

\begin{document}
    Hello.你好.
\end{document}
```

compile->view.

I only can see the English word"Hello",the Chinese word "你好" can not be displayed.

How can I fixed the software or configure something any more?Can someone help me ?

---

Some more information added here:

1.I open Vim editor ,type in ..."你好"....，I can see the Chinese characters"你好",then compile ,view , I can not see the Chinese characters"你好"in the *.pdf file.

2.Exit(shutdown)the Vim editor,open the same source tex file with TeXworks,before I compile the source tex file,I can not see the Chinese characters"你好",after I compile the source tex file I also can not see the Chinese characters"你好"in the *.pdf file.

3.I check the source tex file in Notepad++ ,I got that the source tex file created by Vim editor is encoding in ANSI.

Is it a encoding problem?I have googled a lot ,but can not solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good answer about writeing Simplified Chinese in Latex.

[How does one type Chinese in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17611/how-does-one-type-chinese-in-latex)

You should begin the document like that:

```
\documentclass[UTF8]{ctexart}
\begin{document} 
hello. 你好！
\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}

\begin{document}
Hello.你好
\end{document}
```

They all make sense for me in **texlive+Vim+latex-suite** and **texlive+texmaker.**

Comment: I have tried your method.It can not display the Chinese charactors.

Comment: Maybe change the encode to UTF8?

Comment: I have tried to change the source tex file to UTF8 encoding mechanism by using the Notepad++ editor.Save the source tex file.Then I open the source tex file ,but the vim itself changes the source tex file to ANSI encoding .Can not compile or view .