# How to typeset Chinese font appropriately: \usepackage{xeCJK} give Chinese as mess code

Tags: fonts, languages, cjk

I asked [a question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/385586/quote-a-dictum-in-chinese-in-a-new-page-before-my-thesis-in-english) about typesetting a few Chinese characters in a new page in a report. This problem seems to have been solved by gusbrs and egreg. However, when I use exactly the answers both give me mess code as follows.
Thus, I believe now my problem becomes how to use Chinese font appropriately in Latex?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{lmodern}%for quote page
\newlength\longest

\begin{document}
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\null\vfill


\settowidth\longest{\huge 我正在认真学习的中文。}
\centering
\parbox{\longest}{%
  \raggedright{\huge%
  我正在认真学习的中文。\\
  北京；\\
  彩虹；\\
  柔中带刚。   \par\bigskip
  }
  \raggedleft\Large 《语文$\bm{\cdot}$长城》 \par%
}


\vfill\vfill

\clearpage

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should check the encoding of your tex document. It need to be saved in **UTF8**.