# Why is CJK not supported by default?

Tags: xetex, unicode, languages, cjk, xecjk

It is possible to process Chinese, Japanese and Korean text using the [`xeCJK`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xecjk) package or the `xtexart` document class, as shown in the Q&A “[How does one type Chinese in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17611/how-does-one-type-chinese-in-latex/55893)”.

But why are these steps necessary? That is to say, how is CJK handled differently from the latin alphabet, considering that xetex supports Unicode, and that there are numerous Chinese fonts available?

Given the following example (to be compiled with xelatex), why is there (simplified and traditional) Chinese output, whereas there’s only a blank page when `xeCJK` is removed?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\begin{document}
国國
\end{document}
```

Comment: Because the default font (Latin Modern) doesn't have support for Chinese?

Comment: Even the (extended) Latin alphabets don't work out of the box. For example  `\documentclass{article} \begin{document} château \end{document}` misses the Unicode character `â`. In this case `fontspec` is required: `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{fontspec} \begin{document} château \end{document}`.

Comment: You are both absolutely right. Removing xeCJK and specifying a Chinese font with polyglossia works fine. I didn’t consider that it could simply be a matter of the standard font.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot When I compile your example without fontspec, the character â is processed correctly, though. (xelatex on linux).

Comment: Okay, I figured out the easiest way to achieve what I’d like to do is to define `\newfontfamily\CJK[]{Source Han Sans}` and use it by invoking `{\chin _my text_} inside the document. This is described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25249/how-do-i-use-a-particular-font-for-a-small-section-of-text-in-my-document/37251#37251).

Comment: @NicolaTalbot this is no longer true, in a current latex format the default font setup for xelatex and lualatex has changed and the â will show correctly out of the box.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It didn't show for me but I haven't updated from TL 2016 yet.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Even `ŵ` works now ;).

Comment: @cfr Now works for me too :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without `xeCJK`, the default Latin Modern font is used, and this does not have support for CJK glyphs. (Unsurprisingly perhaps, given the name.)

Hence, if you set a default font that does have support for these characters (which is part of what `xeCJK` does), you do get something. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Sans CJK SC}
\begin{document}
国國
\end{document}
```

[image]