# Is XeTex included in texlive linux package?

Tags: xetex, texlive, linux, pinyin

[After viewing this tutorial](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17611/how-does-one-type-chinese-in-latex), I am trying to view Chinese characters on latex. The tutorial recommends XeTex, does the texlive linux package already contain XeTex? I currently do not have the ctex package installed and was wondering how to implement it into texlive?

Comment: yes by default xetex is included ctex is also included by default but `tlmgr install ctex` should install it (if you are using texlive from tug)

Comment: A linux package is not really meaningful without a distribution. Are you using Ubuntu/Debian? Then please post which Linux packages you have installed. If you mean the vanilla TeX Live from TUG (their linux version) you can proceed as David Carlisle advised.

Comment: If you’re using Debian, look up the package page (it’s https://packages.debian.org/stretch/texlive-binaries for Debian stable), find your architecture at the bottom of the page, and click on “list of files” (https://packages.debian.org/stretch/i386/texlive-binaries/filelist), where you will find `/usr/bin/xetex` listed.  I assume that other Linux distributions provide similar information about their packages.