# Inserting Chinese text

Tags: characters, chinese

I am using `\documentclass[UTF8,12pt, twoside]{extreport}` with PDFLaTeX on TeXmaker on Windows and I successfully created PDF documents when Chinese text is not added. I need to put some pages with traditional Chinese text.
For this, I followed [How does one type Chinese in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17611/how-does-one-type-chinese-in-latex) and used `\usepackage{CJKutf8}`, `\usepackage{ucs}` and `\usepackage[encapsulated]{CJK}`. 
It gave following errors.

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char − (U+2212)
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char (U+2009)
```

Am I missing something here? Is there any unicode issues with packages and the `\usepackage{CJKutf8}` ?

I am relatively new user of LaTeX. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: please provide a full MWE.

Comment: Check the following link:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17611/how-does-one-type-chinese-in-latex

Comment: I would recommend that you use XeLaTeX and the `fontspec` package, which will let you enter Chinese in UTF-8 and display it with an OpenType font. I'm not familiar enough with the Chinese packages out there to write an adequate answer, but PDFtex is unlikely to meet your needs.

Comment: Use `xeCJK` with XeLaTeX as suggested by Leo Liu, one of the developers of `CTeX` in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17637/164314).