# XeLaTeX: Chinese characters

Tags: xetex, languages, characters, cjk, chinese

Firstly, apologies for my ignorance but I have tried all the options given in: [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17611/how-does-one-type-chinese-in-latex). However, I still am unable to get it working.

From the above post, I am trying to achieve this:

```
% Compile with xelatex
% UTF-8 encoding
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{SimSun}
\begin{document}
文章内容
\end{document}
```

And compiling from either Texmaker or the command line using: `xelatex file.tex` does not work.

I get the error:

> fontspec error: "fond-not-found"!! The font SimSun cannot be found.!! ...

I'm sorry again but I've found the online material regarding this problem to be very difficult to understand.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04

**How do I get this to compile properly?**

Comment: Do you have the font *SimSun* installed?

Comment: @DavidPurton I don't know, how do I check / try?

Comment: XeTeX uses system fonts. So can you use *SimSun* in other applications? (e.g., a Word Processor.)

Comment: I don't know how to check if I can use _SimSun_ else where

Comment: If you don't have *SimSun* (which you might not if you don't own Microsoft products) you can use *any* font installed on your computer that supports CJK characters. If you don't have any, you could use the [Noto fonts](https://www.google.com/get/noto/help/cjk/) which are free.

Comment: What Operating System do you use?

Comment: I am on Ubuntu 16.04. When you say: `you can use any font installed on your computer that supports CJK characters`, what do you mean by that? Are you referring to entering the characters into the `.tex` document?

Comment: *SimSin* is the name of a font. (Like *Times New Roman* is the name of a font.). Your problem is that you don't have *SimSun* installed on your computer. You don't have to use *SimSun*, but you do need a font that includes Chinese characters. Installing fonts for your computer is offtopic for this site, so you will need to ask elsewhere. In your `tex` file you could try changing `\setCJKmainfont{SimSun}` to `\setCJKmainfont{Noto Sans CJK}` which you may already have installed on your computer.

Comment: Okay, I will try to install a new font. Thank you

Comment: @DavidPurton Could you point me in the right direction for seeking help regarding installing new fonts? I don't understand how / where to install which fonts and can't find instructions / steps online.

Comment: On Ubuntu, you can check whether a font is installed with `fc-match`. Install a font by copying the files (normally `.otf`) into `/usr/local/share/fonts/` to install them for everyone, or create a directory `~/.fonts/` and copy them there to install only for yourself.

Comment: If you dual-boot Windows, you can also use `ln -s` to add symbolic links from `/Windows/Fonts` on your Windows partition to your local Linux font directory.

Comment: You might also find `otfinfo` and `fc-list` helpful for finding information on font files.

Comment: I have downloaded several `NotoSansSC` `.otf` files and put them in `/usr/local/share/fonts` and rebooted, however the XeLaTeX complication is still failing due to the "font-not-found" error from using `\setCJKmainfont{Noto Sans CJK}`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87390/discussion-between-user9506231-and-davislor).

Comment: By the way, on Ubuntu, use `apt search` or an online search to figure out if there’s a Ubuntu or Debian package for the font you’re looking for. Let your package manager handle it if possible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the issue, I had to follow these steps:

1. Download the fonts to use (I used Noto Sans CJK)
2. Put the font files (.otf) in `/usr/local/share/fonts`
3. After rebooting, use this line to tell XeLaTeX to get those fonts: `\setCJKmainfont{Noto Sans CJK SC}`

Comment: Is "Noto Sans CJK SC" in the the setCJKmainfont command the name of the file without extension?