# It is possible to use ctex in MikTeX/TeXworks?

Tags: miktex, texworks, ctex

I have been using MikTeX/TeXworks for a while and have really enjoyed its universality and facility. I usually compile laTeX documents with XeLaTeX or pdfLaTeX. However, I was not able to input Chinese characters with TeXworks. For instance, I have installed the ctex and few CJK related packages using the MikTeX console, and the tex document does not seem to compile properly. To be specific, I do not get a single Chinese character from the output pdf file.

In [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17611/how-does-one-type-chinese-in-latex) stackexchange question, it explains how to utilize ctex package with XeLaTeX or pdfLaTeX. But I do not compile my laTeX documents under linux, neither want to install the entire all-in-one ctex software. On the other hand, the [overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Chinese) site provides the environment to work with ctex, and it seems to work fine.

Therefore, I understand that in principle, what I wanted to achieve is not impossible, but what is a minimal amount of style file installation one needs in order to use ctex or ctexart package under Miktex? Many thanks in advance!

**Edit1**

The following example is from the overleaf site, which complies fine there. MikTeX will stop and try to install certain package and stays there forever, even after I installed ctex package by using its console.

```
\documentclass{ctexart}
\begin{document}
\section{中文标题}
中文内容
\end{document}
```

**Edit2**

Following the example given by *Ulrike Fischer* in his answer, I got the following log file:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (MiKTeX 2.9.7250 64-bit)
(preloaded format=xelatex 2019.11.25)  6 FEB 2020 17:50
entering extended mode
**"G:/My Drive/test.tex"
("G:/My Drive/test.tex"
LaTeX2e <2019-10-01> patch level 3
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/ctex\ctexart.cls"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3.sty"
Package: expl3 2020-02-03 L3 programming layer (loader) 

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3-code.tex"
Package: expl3 2020-02-03 L3 programming layer (code)
\c_max_int=\count80
\l_tmpa_int=\count81
\l_tmpb_int=\count82
\g_tmpa_int=\count83
\g_tmpb_int=\count84
\l__seq_internal_a_int=\count85
\l__seq_internal_b_int=\count86
\g__kernel_prg_map_int=\count87
\c__ior_term_noprompt_ior=\count88
\c_log_iow=\count89
\l_iow_line_count_int=\count90
\l__iow_line_target_int=\count91
\l__iow_one_indent_int=\count92
\l__iow_indent_int=\count93
\c_zero_dim=\dimen102
\c_max_dim=\dimen103
\l_tmpa_dim=\dimen104
\l_tmpb_dim=\dimen105
\g_tmpa_dim=\dimen106
\g_tmpb_dim=\dimen107
\c_zero_skip=\skip41
\c_max_skip=\skip42
\l_tmpa_skip=\skip43
\l_tmpb_skip=\skip44
\g_tmpa_skip=\skip45
\g_tmpb_skip=\skip46
\c_zero_muskip=\muskip10
\c_max_muskip=\muskip11
\l_tmpa_muskip=\muskip12
\l_tmpb_muskip=\muskip13
\g_tmpa_muskip=\muskip14
\g_tmpb_muskip=\muskip15
\l_keys_choice_int=\count94
\l__intarray_loop_int=\count95
\c__intarray_sp_dim=\dimen108
\g__intarray_font_int=\count96
\c__fp_leading_shift_int=\count97
\c__fp_middle_shift_int=\count98
\c__fp_trailing_shift_int=\count99
\c__fp_big_leading_shift_int=\count100
\c__fp_big_middle_shift_int=\count101
\c__fp_big_trailing_shift_int=\count102
\c__fp_Bigg_leading_shift_int=\count103
\c__fp_Bigg_middle_shift_int=\count104
\c__fp_Bigg_trailing_shift_int=\count105
\g__fp_array_int=\count106
\l__fp_array_loop_int=\count107
\l__sort_length_int=\count108
\l__sort_min_int=\count109
\l__sort_top_int=\count110
\l__sort_max_int=\count111
\l__sort_true_max_int=\count112
\l__sort_block_int=\count113
\l__sort_begin_int=\count114
\l__sort_end_int=\count115
\l__sort_A_int=\count116
\l__sort_B_int=\count117
\l__sort_C_int=\count118
\l__str_internal_int=\count119
\l__tl_analysis_normal_int=\count120
\l__tl_analysis_index_int=\count121
\l__tl_analysis_nesting_int=\count122
\l__tl_analysis_type_int=\count123
\l__regex_internal_a_int=\count124
\l__regex_internal_b_int=\count125
\l__regex_internal_c_int=\count126
\l__regex_balance_int=\count127
\l__regex_group_level_int=\count128
\l__regex_mode_int=\count129
\c__regex_cs_in_class_mode_int=\count130
\c__regex_cs_mode_int=\count131
\l__regex_catcodes_int=\count132
\l__regex_default_catcodes_int=\count133
\c__regex_catcode_L_int=\count134
\c__regex_catcode_O_int=\count135
\c__regex_catcode_A_int=\count136
\c__regex_all_catcodes_int=\count137
\l__regex_show_lines_int=\count138
\l__regex_min_state_int=\count139
\l__regex_max_state_int=\count140
\l__regex_left_state_int=\count141
\l__regex_right_state_int=\count142
\l__regex_capturing_group_int=\count143
\l__regex_min_pos_int=\count144
\l__regex_max_pos_int=\count145
\l__regex_curr_pos_int=\count146
\l__regex_start_pos_int=\count147
\l__regex_success_pos_int=\count148
\l__regex_curr_char_int=\count149
\l__regex_curr_catcode_int=\count150
\l__regex_last_char_int=\count151
\l__regex_case_changed_char_int=\count152
\l__regex_curr_state_int=\count153
\l__regex_step_int=\count154
\l__regex_min_active_int=\count155
\l__regex_max_active_int=\count156
\l__regex_replacement_csnames_int=\count157
\l__regex_match_count_int=\count158
\l__regex_min_submatch_int=\count159
\l__regex_submatch_int=\count160
\l__regex_zeroth_submatch_int=\count161
\g__regex_trace_regex_int=\count162
\c_empty_box=\box27
\l_tmpa_box=\box28
\l_tmpb_box=\box29
\g_tmpa_box=\box30
\g_tmpb_box=\box31
\l__box_top_dim=\dimen109
\l__box_bottom_dim=\dimen110
\l__box_left_dim=\dimen111
\l__box_right_dim=\dimen112
\l__box_top_new_dim=\dimen113
\l__box_bottom_new_dim=\dimen114
\l__box_left_new_dim=\dimen115
\l__box_right_new_dim=\dimen116
\l__box_internal_box=\box32
\l__coffin_internal_box=\box33
\l__coffin_internal_dim=\dimen117
\l__coffin_offset_x_dim=\dimen118
\l__coffin_offset_y_dim=\dimen119
\l__coffin_x_dim=\dimen120
\l__coffin_y_dim=\dimen121
\l__coffin_x_prime_dim=\dimen122
\l__coffin_y_prime_dim=\dimen123
\c_empty_coffin=\box34
\l__coffin_aligned_coffin=\box35
\l__coffin_aligned_internal_coffin=\box36
\l_tmpa_coffin=\box37
\l_tmpb_coffin=\box38
\g_tmpa_coffin=\box39
\g_tmpb_coffin=\box40
\l__coffin_bounding_shift_dim=\dimen124
\l__coffin_left_corner_dim=\dimen125
\l__coffin_right_corner_dim=\dimen126
\l__coffin_bottom_corner_dim=\dimen127
\l__coffin_top_corner_dim=\dimen128
\l__coffin_scaled_total_height_dim=\dimen129
\l__coffin_scaled_width_dim=\dimen130
\c__coffin_empty_coffin=\box41
\l__coffin_display_coffin=\box42
\l__coffin_display_coord_coffin=\box43
\l__coffin_display_pole_coffin=\box44
\l__coffin_display_offset_dim=\dimen131
\l__coffin_display_x_dim=\dimen132
\l__coffin_display_y_dim=\dimen133
\g__char_data_ior=\read1

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3kernel\l3deprecation.def"
File: l3deprecation.def 2019-04-06 v L3 Deprecated functions
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-xdvipdfmx.def"
File: l3backend-xdvipdfmx.def 2020-02-03 L3 backend support: xdvipdfmx
\g__graphics_track_int=\count163
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box45
\g__pdf_backend_object_int=\count164
\g__pdf_backend_annotation_int=\count165
))
Document Class: ctexart 2019/05/29 v2.4.16 Chinese adapter for class article (C
TEX)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3packages/xparse\xparse.sty"
Package: xparse 2020-02-03 L3 Experimental document command parser
\l__xparse_current_arg_int=\count166
\g__xparse_grabber_int=\count167
\l__xparse_m_args_int=\count168
\l__xparse_v_nesting_int=\count169
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e\l3keys2e.sty"
Package: l3keys2e 2020-02-03 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/ctex\ctexhook.sty"
Package: ctexhook 2019/05/29 v2.4.16 Document and package hooks (CTEX)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/ctex\ctexpatch.sty"
Package: ctexpatch 2019/05/29 v2.4.16 Patching commands (CTEX)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\fix-cm.sty"
Package: fix-cm 2015/01/14 v1.1t fixes to LaTeX

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\ts1enc.def"
File: ts1enc.def 2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/ms\everysel.sty"
Package: everysel 2011/10/28 v1.2 EverySelectfont Package (MS)
)
\l__ctex_tmp_int=\count170
\l__ctex_tmp_box=\box46
\l__ctex_tmp_dim=\dimen134
\g__ctex_section_depth_int=\count171
\g__ctex_font_size_int=\count172

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/ctex/config\ctexopts.cfg"
File: ctexopts.cfg 2019/05/29 v2.4.16 Option configuration file (CTEX)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2019/10/25 v1.4k Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2019/10/25 v1.4k Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count173
\c@section=\count174
\c@subsection=\count175
\c@subsubsection=\count176
\c@paragraph=\count177
\c@subparagraph=\count178
\c@figure=\count179
\c@table=\count180
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen135
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/ctex/engine\ctex-engine-xetex.def"
File: ctex-engine-xetex.def 2019/05/29 v2.4.16 XeLaTeX adapter (CTEX)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/xelatex/xecjk\xeCJK.sty"
Package: xeCJK 2019/06/02 v3.7.4 Typesetting CJK scripts with XeLaTeX

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3packages/xtemplate\xtemplate.sty"
Package: xtemplate 2020-02-03 L3 Experimental prototype document functions
\l__xtemplate_tmp_dim=\dimen136
\l__xtemplate_tmp_int=\count181
\l__xtemplate_tmp_muskip=\muskip16
\l__xtemplate_tmp_skip=\skip49
)
\l__xeCJK_tmp_int=\count182
\l__xeCJK_tmp_box=\box47
\l__xeCJK_tmp_dim=\dimen137
\l__xeCJK_tmp_skip=\skip50
\g__xeCJK_space_factor_int=\count183
\l__xeCJK_begin_int=\count184
\l__xeCJK_end_int=\count185
\c__xeCJK_CJK_class_int=\XeTeXcharclass1
\c__xeCJK_FullLeft_class_int=\XeTeXcharclass2
\c__xeCJK_FullRight_class_int=\XeTeXcharclass3
\c__xeCJK_HalfLeft_class_int=\XeTeXcharclass4
\c__xeCJK_HalfRight_class_int=\XeTeXcharclass5
\c__xeCJK_NormalSpace_class_int=\XeTeXcharclass6
\c__xeCJK_CM_class_int=\XeTeXcharclass7
\c__xeCJK_HangulJamo_class_int=\XeTeXcharclass8
\l__xeCJK_last_skip=\skip51
\g__xeCJK_node_int=\count186
\c__xeCJK_CJK_node_dim=\dimen138
\c__xeCJK_CJK-space_node_dim=\dimen139
\c__xeCJK_default_node_dim=\dimen140
\c__xeCJK_default-space_node_dim=\dimen141
\c__xeCJK_CJK-widow_node_dim=\dimen142
\c__xeCJK_normalspace_node_dim=\dimen143
\l__xeCJK_ccglue_skip=\skip52
\l__xeCJK_ecglue_skip=\skip53
\l__xeCJK_punct_kern_skip=\skip54
\l__xeCJK_last_penalty_int=\count187
\l__xeCJK_last_bound_dim=\dimen144
\l__xeCJK_last_kern_dim=\dimen145
\l__xeCJK_widow_penalty_int=\count188

Package xtemplate Info: Declaring object type 'xeCJK/punctuation' taking 0
(xtemplate)             argument(s) on line 2323.

\l__xeCJK_fixed_punct_width_dim=\dimen146
\l__xeCJK_mixed_punct_width_dim=\dimen147
\l__xeCJK_middle_punct_width_dim=\dimen148
\l__xeCJK_fixed_margin_width_dim=\dimen149
\l__xeCJK_mixed_margin_width_dim=\dimen150
\l__xeCJK_middle_margin_width_dim=\dimen151
\l__xeCJK_bound_punct_width_dim=\dimen152
\l__xeCJK_bound_margin_width_dim=\dimen153
\l__xeCJK_margin_minimum_dim=\dimen154
\l__xeCJK_kerning_total_width_dim=\dimen155
\l__xeCJK_same_align_margin_dim=\dimen156
\l__xeCJK_different_align_margin_dim=\dimen157
\l__xeCJK_kerning_margin_width_dim=\dimen158
\l__xeCJK_kerning_margin_minimum_dim=\dimen159
\l__xeCJK_bound_dim=\dimen160
\l__xeCJK_reverse_bound_dim=\dimen161
\l__xeCJK_margin_dim=\dimen162
\l__xeCJK_minimum_bound_dim=\dimen163
\l__xeCJK_kerning_margin_dim=\dimen164
\g__xeCJK_family_int=\count189
\l__xeCJK_fam_int=\count190
\g__xeCJK_fam_allocation_int=\count191
\l__xeCJK_verb_case_int=\count192
\l__xeCJK_verb_exspace_skip=\skip55

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/fontspec\fontspec.sty"
Package: fontspec 2019/10/19 v2.7d Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/fontspec\fontspec-xetex.sty"
Package: fontspec-xetex 2019/10/19 v2.7d Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTe
X
\l__fontspec_script_int=\count193
\l__fontspec_language_int=\count194
\l__fontspec_strnum_int=\count195
\l__fontspec_tmp_int=\count196
\l__fontspec_tmpa_int=\count197
\l__fontspec_tmpb_int=\count198
\l__fontspec_tmpc_int=\count199
\l__fontspec_em_int=\count266
\l__fontspec_emdef_int=\count267
\l__fontspec_strong_int=\count268
\l__fontspec_strongdef_int=\count269
\l__fontspec_tmpa_dim=\dimen165
\l__fontspec_tmpb_dim=\dimen166
\l__fontspec_tmpc_dim=\dimen167

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\fontenc.sty"
Package: fontenc 2018/08/11 v2.0j Standard LaTeX package

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\tuenc.def"
File: tuenc.def 2018/08/11 v2.0j Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding TU on input line 82.
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/fontspec\fontspec.cfg")
LaTeX Info: Redefining \itshape on input line 4047.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \slshape on input line 4052.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \scshape on input line 4057.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \upshape on input line 4062.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \em on input line 4092.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \emph on input line 4117.
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/xelatex/xecjk\xeCJK.cfg"
File: xeCJK.cfg 2019/06/02 v3.7.4 Configuration file for xeCJK package
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/xelatex/xecjk\xeCJKfntef.sty"
Package: xeCJKfntef 2019/06/02 v3.7.4 xeCJK font effect

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/ulem\ulem.sty"
\UL@box=\box48
\UL@hyphenbox=\box49
\UL@skip=\skip56
\UL@hook=\toks14
\UL@height=\dimen168
\UL@pe=\count270
\UL@pixel=\dimen169
\ULC@box=\box50
Package: ulem 2019/11/18
\ULdepth=\dimen170
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/cjk\CJKfntef.sty"
Package: CJKfntef 2015/04/18 4.8.4
\CJK@fntefSkip=\skip57
\CJK@nest=\count271
\CJK@fntefDimen=\dimen171
\CJK@underdotBox=\box51
\CJK@ULbox=\box52
\CJK@underanyskip=\dimen172
)
\l__xeCJK_space_skip=\skip58
\c__xeCJK_ulem-begin_node_dim=\dimen173
\c__xeCJK_null_box=\box53
\l__xeCJK_fntef_box=\box54
\l__xeCJK_under_symbol_box=\box55
\c__xeCJK_filll_skip=\skip59
)
\ccwd=\dimen174
\l__ctex_ccglue_skip=\skip60
)
\l__ctex_ziju_dim=\dimen175

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/zhnumber\zhnumber.sty"
Package: zhnumber 2019/04/07 v2.7 Typesetting numbers with Chinese glyphs
\l__zhnum_scale_int=\count272

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/zhnumber\zhnumber-utf8.cfg"
File: zhnumber-utf8.cfg 2019/04/07 v2.7 Chinese numerals with UTF8 encoding
))
\l__ctex_heading_skip=\skip61

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/ctex/scheme\ctex-scheme-chinese-article
.def"
File: ctex-scheme-chinese-article.def 2019/05/29 v2.4.16 Chinese scheme for art
icle (CTEX)
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/ctex/config\ctex-name-utf8.cfg"
File: ctex-name-utf8.cfg 2019/05/29 v2.4.16 Caption with encoding UTF8 (CTEX)
)) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/ctex\ctex-c5size.clo"
File: ctex-c5size.clo 2019/05/29 v2.4.16 c5size option (CTEX)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/ctex/fontset\ctex-fontset-fandol.def"
File: ctex-fontset-fandol.def 2019/05/29 v2.4.16 Fandol fonts definition (CTEX)



Package fontspec Warning: Font "FandolSong-Regular" does not contain requested
(fontspec)                Script "CJK".


Package fontspec Info: Font family 'FandolSong-Regular(0)' created for font
(fontspec)             'FandolSong-Regular' with options
(fontspec)             [Script={CJK},Extension={.otf},BoldFont={FandolSong-Bold
},ItalicFont={FandolKai-Regular}].
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"[FandolSong-Regular.otf]/OT"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             - 'bold' (bx/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"[FandolSong-Bold.otf]/OT"
(fontspec)             - 'bold small caps'  (bx/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             - 'italic' (m/it) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"[FandolKai-Regular.otf]/OT"
(fontspec)             - 'italic small caps'  (m/itsc) with NFSS spec.: 

)) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/ctex/config\ctex.cfg"
File: ctex.cfg 2019/05/29 v2.4.16 Configuration file (CTEX)
) (test.aux)
\openout1 = `test.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.

ABD: EverySelectfont initializing macros
LaTeX Info: Redefining \selectfont on input line 3.

Package fontspec Info: Adjusting the maths setup (use [no-math] to avoid
(fontspec)             this).

\symlegacymaths=\mathgroup4
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `legacymaths' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/cmr/bx/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \acute on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \grave on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \ddot on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \tilde on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \bar on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \breve on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \check on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \hat on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \dot on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \mathring on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \colon on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Gamma on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Delta on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Theta on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Lambda on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Xi on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Pi on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Sigma on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Upsilon on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Phi on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Psi on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Omega on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \mathdollar on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `operators' on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `normal' on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> TU/lmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `bold' on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/lmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  TU/lmr/m/n --> TU/lmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> TU/lmr/m/it on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/lmr/bx/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> TU/lmss/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/lmtt/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  TU/lmr/m/n --> TU/lmr/bx/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> TU/lmr/bx/it on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> TU/lmss/bx/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/lmtt/bx/n on input line 3.
Requested font "[lmroman17-regular]:mapping=tex-text;" at 15.05624pt
 -> C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman17-regular.otf
Requested font "[lmroman12-bold]:mapping=tex-text;" at 15.05624pt
 -> C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman12-bold.otf
Requested font "[FandolSong-Bold.otf]/OT" at 15.05624pt
 -> C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/opentype/public/fandol/FandolSong-Bold.ot
f
Requested font "[lmromanslant10-regular]:mapping=tex-text;" at 10.53937pt
 -> C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmromanslant10-regular
.otf
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/FandolSong-Regular(0)/m/sl' in size <10.5393
7> not available
(Font)              Font shape `TU/FandolSong-Regular(0)/m/it' tried instead on
 input line 6.
 [1

] (test.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 18614 strings out of 427240
 423516 string characters out of 3145703
 496948 words of memory out of 3000000
 23061 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 532548 words of font info for 38 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1348 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 58i,4n,76p,417b,2146s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s

Output written on test.pdf (1 page).
```

Comment: Show a small complete example that demonstrates what doesn't work so that one can test the issue.

Comment: I added a small piece of example which is copied and slightly modified from that of the overleaf site. @Ulrike Fischer

Answer (score 2):

Try a different fontset:

```
\documentclass[fontset=fandol]{ctexart}
\begin{document}
\section{中文标题}
中文内容
\end{document}
```

[image]

The default windows fontset of ctex  tries to load a font which is not  (or not longer or perhaps only in some cases) in windows.

Comment: I really appreciate for the help. Now it compiles but still not showing any Chinese characters. The only warning msg I found in the log file is "Package fontspec Warning: Font "FandolSong-Regular" does not contain requested
(fontspec)                Script "CJK"." What else I should look for instead of sending the entire log file? Again, many thanks!

Comment: add \XeTeXtracingfonts=1 (assuming that you are using xelatex) and then show the log.

Comment: Thanks! Here is the log file https://gofile.io/?c=mZZZ4v

Comment: Don't sent a log from an unknown source document. My example doesn't produce 5 pages.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I appended the log output to the original question, for some reason it is rather large. Please take a look. Again, appreciated!