# How to show Chinese characters in LaTeXiT

Tags: xetex, mactex, xecjk, latexit

I try to render some math equations using LaTeXiT, but Chinese characters does not show correctly:
[image]

The text I tried to render is `english 中文 English`.

I made the following setup:

1. add `\usepackage{xeCJK}` to LaTeXiT preamble
2. Set LaTeXiT to use XeLaTeX engine in the Typesetting section:
   [image]

I also made sure that TexShop can show Chinese characters correctly after adding `\usepackage{xeCJK}` and use XeLaTeX. Also I found no error in the LaTeXiT log.

How do I setup LaTeXiT to show Chinese characters correctly?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please show the code you're trying to run, rather than a screenshot of fragments of said code.

Comment: unrelated but do not use `inputenc` with xelatex, it does nothing other than generate a warning that `inputenc` should not be used.

Comment: Side Note: Assuming you installed TeX Live 2021 with the MacTeX installer Preferences setting for pdflatex and xelated should be `/Library/TeX/texbin`. That way it will always point to the active TeX distribution. I know I'd forget what I've done and then will be puzzled when I change active distributions and no longer have TeX Live 2021.

Comment: Maybe, more general information about how to typeset Chinese with (La)TeX can help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17611/47927

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a solution on a Chinese website, and the solution is to embrace Chinese characters in `\mbox`, for example: `English \mbox{中文} English`
[image]

Comment: @DavidCarlisle LaTeXiT is an equation editor (https://www.chachatelier.fr/latexit/latexit-features.php), so what could be happening could be symbol-related in that `$x+y=z  \mbox{中文}$` shows the Chinese characters under `xeCJK` with xelatex, but `$x+y=z  中文$` does not.

Comment: @Cicada ah yes thanks, I deleted the first comment